# How to Encode from Extjs.Class to JSON String?

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4

I want to Encode EXTjs Class to Json, But, I can't..

I use JSON.stringify, but that gives Exception with Type error.

How can I do that?

Thanks and Here my Code.

```
Ext.define('Text',{
    extend : 'Ext.Img',
    x : 50,
    y : 50,
    size : 100,
    text : 'Text',
    name : 'Text',
    src : ' ',
    tag : '',
    Events : []
});

var text = new Text();
var temp = JSON.stringify(text);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that ExtJS creates internal references on the objects, which turn out to be cyclical. Thus, the default JSON serializer fails.

You need to manually define a `toJSON` method which will be called by `JSON.stringify`:

```
Ext.define('Text', {
    extend : 'Ext.Img',
    x : 50,
    y : 50,
    size : 100,
    text : 'Text',
    name : 'Text',
    src : ' ',
    tag : '',
    Events : [],

    toJSON: function () {
        return 'Whatever you like' + this.text + this.size // etc.
    }

});

JSON.stringify(new Text()); // "Whatever you likeText100"
```

Answer (score 8):

try using

```
Ext.encode(Object)
```

it Encodes an Object, Array or other value & returns The JSON string.

refer [Ext.JSON](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.JSON)

[serialize object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382167/serializing-object-that-contains-cyclic-object-value)

Comment: I tried, but Error..
'RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded'

Comment: try `var seen = [];

var temp = JSON.stringify(text, function(key, val) {
   if (typeof val == "object") {
        if (seen.indexOf(val) >= 0)
            return undefined
        seen.push(val)
    }
    return val
}); console.log(temp);
`

Comment: But, I solve this problem, but it is not smart.. I made parser for Class. That error's cause is the Ext core is include in Class. So I made Parser. I get Idea from your answer. Thanks! If you know other way, Please tell me.