# Stringify and parse JSON (serializing an object structure) and deserializing, converting a JSON string into an object structure?

Tags: javascript, json, object

Can anyone guide me how I do this in Javascript? Create an object with two methods. It should stringify and parse JSON, ie it has a method of serializing an object structure, and another method for deserializing, converting a JSON string into an object structure.

Methods Should handle circular references, not kracha or retunera an empty result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to parse json in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript) and [serializing object that contains cyclic object value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382167/serializing-object-that-contains-cyclic-object-value) -- please use the search before you ask a new question.

Comment: *Methods Should handle circular references* How exactly should they be handled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse`

```
var originalObject = { foo: "bar" };
var jsonString = JSON.stringify( originalObject ); // "{foo:'bar'}"
var objectFromString = JSON.parse( jsonString );   // { foo: "bar" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Err.. [JSON.parse and JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON#Parsing_JSON.C2.A0strings)? It's pretty much [supported these days](http://caniuse.com/#search=json).