# How can I print a circular structure in a JSON-like format?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a big object I want to convert to JSON and send. However it has circular structure, so if I try to use `JSON.stringify()` I'll get:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

or

> TypeError: cyclic object value

I want to toss whatever circular references exist and send whatever can be stringified. How do I do that?

Thanks.

```
var obj = {
  a: "foo",
  b: obj
}
```

I want to stringify obj into:

```
{"a":"foo"}
```

Comment: Could you please post a sample object with a circular reference that you'd like to parse ?

Comment: something like [this](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/06/17/json-referencing-in-dojo/)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [serializing object that contains cyclic object value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382167/serializing-object-that-contains-cyclic-object-value)

Comment: Late to the party but there is a [github](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23961876/2464634) project to handle this.

Comment: closely related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117470/passing-an-object-with-circular-references-from-server-to-client-side-javascript/23961876#23961876

Answer (score 757, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify` with a custom replacer. For example:

```
// Demo: Circular reference
var circ = {};
circ.circ = circ;

// Note: cache should not be re-used by repeated calls to JSON.stringify.
var cache = [];
JSON.stringify(circ, (key, value) => {
  if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
    // Duplicate reference found, discard key
    if (cache.includes(value)) return;

    // Store value in our collection
    cache.push(value);
  }
  return value;
});
cache = null; // Enable garbage collection
```

The replacer in this example is not 100% correct (depending on your definition of "duplicate"). In the following case, a value is discarded:

```
var a = {b:1}
var o = {};
o.one = a;
o.two = a;
// one and two point to the same object, but two is discarded:
JSON.stringify(o, ...);
```

But the concept stands: Use a custom replacer, and keep track of the parsed object values.

As a utility function written in es6:

```js
// safely handles circular references
JSON.safeStringify = (obj, indent = 2) => {
  let cache = [];
  const retVal = JSON.stringify(
    obj,
    (key, value) =>
      typeof value === "object" && value !== null
        ? cache.includes(value)
          ? undefined // Duplicate reference found, discard key
          : cache.push(value) && value // Store value in our collection
        : value,
    indent
  );
  cache = null;
  return retVal;
};

// Example:
console.log('options', JSON.safeStringify(options))
```

Comment: There was a small bug in your code but the overall idea I understand, thanks!

Comment: You should be checking typeof value not typeof cache

Comment: By the way - I ran into an interesting scenario. Someone printed the `attrs` parameters in an AngularJS directive. I think this object is just too big to be printed. Chrome gives up after 2582 keys. So I added to my solution a cache length limit.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(window, ...)` on this page breaks with the exception: `InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('hidden') does not support selection.`

Comment: @BrunoLM Trying to serialize a non-serializable object won't result in anything useful... What would you expect from serializing `window`?

Comment: I'm getting the same error trying to stringify an instance of CKEditor. It saves inside the DOM element associated, so, I can't stringify with this approach

Comment: @CruzDiablo Serializing DOM is usually meaningless. However, if you can think of a meaningful serialization method for your purposes, then you could try to add a custom serialized to DOM objects: `Node.prototype.toJSON = function() { return 'whatever you think that is right'; };` (if you want anything more generic/specific, just try anything in the prototype tree: HTMLDivElement implements HTMLElement implements Element implements Node implements EventTarget; note: this may be browser-dependent, the previous tree is true for Chrome)

Comment: this is wrong because it will skip the second appearance of objects that are contained twice, even if not in a really cyclic structure. `var a={id:1}; JSON.stringify([a,a]);`

Comment: @user2451227 "The replacer in this example is not 100% correct (depending on your definition of "duplicate"). But the concept stands: Use a custom replacer, and keep track of the parsed object values."

Comment: Don't use this indeed. It strips out every duplicate object (which isn't a circular dependency) and is hellishly slow by checking every seen object.

Comment: The GC concern here is arguably redundant. If this is run as a single script then script immediately terminates. If this is encapsulated inside a function for implementation then `cache` will be unreachable https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Comment: Note that IE 8 does not support `Array.prototype.indexOf()`. You may need to polyfill. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: @AndriMöll Pretty sure Rob's just concisely demonstrating custom replacers, which he's done very well. [Preston's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json#comment36916350_11616630) points to some [Crockfordian code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/ad6079cbd8dc362a3cc42e1f97c01aa5ccd48bfe/cycle.js) that is live-fire robust, if that's what you're after. But the concept is the same.

Comment: @ruffin: Since making that comment, I've taken the JSON Stringify Safe lib from Isaac and rewrote it: https://github.com/isaacs/json-stringify-safe.

I'm not sure what the supposedly live-fire robust Crockford code does. It looks overly complicated and seems to do the same poor linear check that I warned against above.

Comment: @AndriMöll using your stringifier and passing in `window` I still get `Error: Permission denied to access property "toJSON" `, it's funny cause it works with any other cyclic test obj but not `window` or 'document`! could there be that there is an intentional limitation placed on the `JSON.stringify` that inhibits it from executing certain objects?

Comment: @SabaAhang: Presumably one of the global objects you're stringifying has a `toJSON` that throws. FYI: By passing in `window` you'll be stringifying _every_ global variable. Probably not a good idea.

Comment: @ruffin: The linear check is worthy of mocking no matter who writes it. ;-) See the code related to the `objects` array and the comment above it: «This is a hard way, linear search that will get slower as the number of unique objects grows.»

Comment: I was using this function without flushing the cache, and this gave very unexpected results. Saving the next guy some headache, i took the liberty to make the cache var local.

Comment: This is correct, but there is a better solution using Map! We can make this more performant using a hashmap, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48254637/1223975

Comment: Small addition helped me reduce useless for debug-purpose info:        if( key.startsWith('_') ) {
            return;
        }

Comment: @WebBrother I know exactly what your problem is, I have known about this situation for years, I just created a fix for this, please try it out: https://github.com/ORESoftware/safe-stringify, look for `stringifyDeep`, try it on your object and see if t works for you.

Comment: @RobW this solution is improved with the try/catch block you added recently, but I found another limitation, see this gist please: https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/10bd74e27728a2aa764df4d6c6ecada8

Comment: Isn't using `indexOf` for each element awfully inefficient (like exponentially)? Wouldn't it be wieser to use `var cache = new Set()` and `cache.has(value)` instead?

Comment: in Arrays it just works fine for the first element then all elements become null

Comment: **Note:** an edit to this question by @funrob in May 2018 fixed the issue with some  items being discarded; I reverted the edit as it changed the substance of the answer (and made the part of the answer that referenced the issue nonsensical, as well as some of the comments), but the fix is to replace the `return;` statement with `try { return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)); } catch (error) { return; }`

Comment: This doesnt work if. `obj1 = {}; obj2 = {foo:obj, bar:obj}` The stringify removes bar because it exists in cache but it is not cyclic.

Comment: magnificent answer, this is terse and helped me as well.

Comment: @AndriMöll Over five years later, I notice that I stand corrected. ;^) [Your "circular stringify" solution](https://github.com/moll/json-stringify-safe/blob/master/stringify.js) does seem much better than [Crockford's](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/ad6079cbd8dc362a3cc42e1f97c01aa5ccd48bfe/cycle.js#L51) in exactly the ways you describe. He's a smart dude, so I'm worried there's something I've missed, but until (and if!) then, a sincere thanks.

Answer (score 911):

In Node.js, you can use [util.inspect(object)](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-options). It automatically replaces circular links with "[Circular]".

---

Albeit being built-in *(no installation is required)*, you must import it

```
import * as util from 'util' // has no default export
import { inspect } from 'util' // or directly
// or 
var util = require('util')
```

##### To use it, simply call

```
console.log(util.inspect(myObject))
```

Also be aware that you can pass options object to inspect *(see link above)*

```
inspect(myObject[, options: {showHidden, depth, colors, showProxy, ...moreOptions}])
```

---

*Please, read and give kudos to commenters below...*

Comment: util is a built-in module, you do not have to install it.

Comment: console.log(util.inspect(obj))

Comment: This was a great suggestion!  Thanks so much!  I never thought seeing a console logged object would be so satisfying, but it was as if you broke all the objs open for me now to work with.

Comment: Note that if for some reason you need to use JSON.stringify, you CANNOT USE util.inspect, because it outputs a string, and not an object.

Comment: One more tip about this: I use util.inspect with the following arguments, console.log(util.inspect(object, false, 10, true));   the second argument is for setting showHiddenProperties to false, the 10 is to tell it to dig into the object up to 10 levels deep and the last 'true' is to ask it to colorize the output.  reference: https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/how-to-use-util-inspect

Comment: @Mitar it is built-in, but you still have to load the module `var util = require('util');`

Comment: Don't be a dunce like me, its *just* `obj_str = util.inspect(thing)`, NOT <s>`garbage_str = JSON.stringify(util.inspect(thing))`</s>

Comment: Do note that util.inspect does not always return valid JSON. For example `util.inspect(new Error('This is an example error'))`

Comment: This is much better than mucking around with checking types. Why can't stringify just work like this? If it knows there's a circular reference, why can't it just be told to ignore it???

Comment: Albeit being built-in, you must import it with either `import * as util from 'util'` or `var util = require('util')`. To use it, simply call `console.log(util.inspect(myObject))`. Also be aware that you can pass additional parameters to `inspect(myObject[, options: {showHidden, depth, colors, showProxy, ...otherOptions}])`.

Comment: OMG it works! `cb(require('util').inspect(sequelize))` thank you so much!

Comment: I imported this into my codebase and it added almost a thousand lines of code

Comment: Just wanted point out that util.insect() will NOT produce valid Json string... so it is kind of different from JSON.stringify()

Comment: `util.inspect()` didn't work for me. It introduces some return characters which could be removed with `string.replace()`. So I just converted it to new object with `Object.assign()` (it happened with firebase firestore data)

Comment: This was very helpful thank you!

Here is an example with the options that prints everything, in case you are debugging a large object. 
let inspectOptions = {showHidden: false, depth:null, maxArrayLength: null   };
let returnVal = util.inspect(thing,inspectOptions);//Debug

Comment: You don't need the 2nd import, since you are referring directly to inspect using util.inspect().

Comment: Note: util.inspect will only indicate `[Circular]` if the "depth" property is large enough to contain the entire cycle; hence

`a = {}; a.b = {}; a.b.c = {}; a.b.c.d = {}; a.b.c.d.e = a; util.inspect(a)` will print `{ b: { c: { d: [Object] } } }` despite the circular reference, but `util.inspect(a, {depth: 3})` will display `[Circular]`

Comment: @ThorSummoner not sure what you mean by that. These docs say you can do `console.log(inspect(obj)`: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/how-to-use-util-inspect/

Answer (score 277):

I wonder why nobody posted the [proper solution from MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cyclic_object_value#Examples) yet...

```js
const circularReference = {otherData: 123};
circularReference.myself = circularReference;

const getCircularReplacer = () => {
  const seen = new WeakSet();
  return (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
      if (seen.has(value)) {
        return;
      }
      seen.add(value);
    }
    return value;
  };
};

const stringified = JSON.stringify(circularReference, getCircularReplacer());

console.log(stringified);
```

Seen values should be stored *in a set*, not in array (replacer gets called **on every element**). Using an array would result in quadratic `O((N^2 + N)/2)` complexity instead of linear `O(N)`!

Note, like in the accepted answer, this solution removes *all repeating values*, not just the circular ones.

Comment: Neat, but this is ES2015 only. No IE support.

Comment: Yoda says: "If still supporting IE one is, then use a transpiler one should."

Comment: ```replacer = () => {
  const seen = new WeakSet();
  return (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
      if (seen.has(value)) {
        return;
      }
      seen.add(value);
    }
    return value;
  };
}
() => {
  const seen = new WeakSet();
  return (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
      if (seen.has(value)) {
        return;
      }
      seen.add(value);
   …
JSON.stringify({a:1, b: '2'}, replacer)```
returns `undefined` in chrome

Comment: I got error `stack.get is not a function` with express' Response object. `decycle` from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js worked.

Comment: This answer (like the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/how-can-i-print-a-circular-structure-in-a-json-like-format#answer-11616993)) has a bug (that is commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/how-can-i-print-a-circular-structure-in-a-json-like-format#comment37945084_11616993) by [user2451227](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2451227/user2451227)), when `o = {}; JSON.stringify([o, o], getCircularReplacer())`.

Comment: @robertotomás, You should **invoke** `replacer()` and pass its return-value (that is another function, that is the actual replacer) to `JSON.stringify()`. Not your `replacer` itself! Mean: `JSON.stringify({a:1, b: '2'}, replacer())`. Name it `getReplacer` for clarity!

Comment: I get `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://mywebsite.local" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Comment: This detects duplicate objects in the structure, not circular.  While a circular will contain a duplicate reference, not all duplicates are circular objects.  So, this removes non-circular references too.  For example with this, `const a = {greeting: "hi"};  const obj = {first: a, second: a};`, using `circular()` when stringifying `obj` will remove the `second` property, even though it is NOT circular at all.  So, it removes unnecessary things.

Answer (score 86):

just do

```
npm i --save circular-json
```

then in your js file

```
const CircularJSON = require('circular-json');
...
const json = CircularJSON.stringify(obj);
```

https://github.com/WebReflection/circular-json

NOTE: I have nothing to do with this package. But I do use it for this.

## Update 2020

Please note CircularJSON is in maintenance only and **[flatted](https://github.com/WebReflection/flatted)** is its successor.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great library, saved tons of time. Super tiny (just 1.4KB minified).

Comment: I think you might require some more justification for using a module than "just do". And it's not great to overwrite `JSON` on principle.

Comment: I needed to copy an object to use for stub testing. This answer was perfect. I copied the object and then removed the override. Thanks!!

Comment: According to the author, this package has been deprecated. CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
Link: https://github.com/WebReflection/flatted#flatted

Comment: Beware, the 'flatted' (and circular-json?) package doesn't replicate JSON.stringify() functionality. It creates its own non-JSON format. (e.g., `Flatted.stringify({blah: 1})` results in `[{"blah":1}]`) I see someone tried to raise an issue about this, and the author berated them and locked the issue to comments.

Comment: Attempt to log object, containing DOM form, caused Visual Studio Code to hang, but [util.inspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/how-can-i-print-a-circular-structure-in-a-json-like-format/18354289#18354289) works.

Answer (score 49):

I really liked Trindaz's solution - more verbose, however it had some bugs. I fixed them for whoever likes it too.

Plus, I added a length limit on my cache objects.

If the object I am printing is really big - I mean infinitely big - I want to limit my algorithm.

```
JSON.stringifyOnce = function(obj, replacer, indent){
    var printedObjects = [];
    var printedObjectKeys = [];

    function printOnceReplacer(key, value){
        if ( printedObjects.length > 2000){ // browsers will not print more than 20K, I don't see the point to allow 2K.. algorithm will not be fast anyway if we have too many objects
        return 'object too long';
        }
        var printedObjIndex = false;
        printedObjects.forEach(function(obj, index){
            if(obj===value){
                printedObjIndex = index;
            }
        });

        if ( key == ''){ //root element
             printedObjects.push(obj);
            printedObjectKeys.push("root");
             return value;
        }

        else if(printedObjIndex+"" != "false" && typeof(value)=="object"){
            if ( printedObjectKeys[printedObjIndex] == "root"){
                return "(pointer to root)";
            }else{
                return "(see " + ((!!value && !!value.constructor) ? value.constructor.name.toLowerCase()  : typeof(value)) + " with key " + printedObjectKeys[printedObjIndex] + ")";
            }
        }else{

            var qualifiedKey = key || "(empty key)";
            printedObjects.push(value);
            printedObjectKeys.push(qualifiedKey);
            if(replacer){
                return replacer(key, value);
            }else{
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
    return JSON.stringify(obj, printOnceReplacer, indent);
};
```

Comment: You're missing a null check on this line : return "(see " + (!!value.constructor ? value.constructor.name.toLowerCase()  : typeof(value)) + " with key " + printedObjectKeys[printedObjIndex] + ")";

Comment: I will gladly add it. just let me know what is nullable as I did experience any problems so far.

Comment: // browsers will not print more than 20K - But you put limit as 2k. Perhaps change for the future?

Answer (score 48):

Note that there is also a `JSON.decycle` method implemented by Douglas Crockford. See his
[cycle.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js). This allows you to stringify almost any standard structure:

```
var a = [];
a[0] = a;
a[1] = 123;
console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.decycle(a)));
// result: '[{"$ref":"$"},123]'.
```

You can also recreate original object with `retrocycle` method. So you don't have to remove cycles from objects to stringify them.

However this will **not** work for DOM Nodes (which are typical cause of cycles in real life use-cases). For example this will throw:

```
var a = [document.body];
console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.decycle(a)));
```

I've made a fork to solve that problem (see my [cycle.js fork](https://github.com/Eccenux/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js)). This should work fine:

```
var a = [document.body];
console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.decycle(a, true)));
```

Note that in my fork `JSON.decycle(variable)` works as in the original and will throw an exception when the `variable` contain DOM nodes/elements.

When you use `JSON.decycle(variable, true)` you accept the fact that the result will not be reversible (retrocycle will not re-create DOM nodes). DOM elements should be identifiable to some extent though. For example if a `div` element has an id then it will be replaced with a string `"div#id-of-the-element"`.

Comment: Both his code and yours give me a "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" when I use them.

Comment: I can have a look if you provide your code on the Fiddle or add an issue on Github: https://github.com/Eccenux/JSON-js/issues

Comment: This is what I was looking for. `JSON.decycle(a, true)` what happens when you pass true as a parameter to decycle function.

Comment: @Rudra true makes `stringifyNodes` option true in the fork. This will dump e.g. `div` with id="some-id" to string: `div#some-id`. You will avoid some problems, but you won't to be able to fully retro-cycle.

Comment: There is npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-js, but it wasn't updated for a while

Comment: Crockford's version worked for me.

Answer (score 42):

@RobW's answer is correct, but this is more performant ! Because it uses a hashmap/set:

```
const customStringify = function (v) {
  const cache = new Set();
  return JSON.stringify(v, function (key, value) {
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
      if (cache.has(value)) {
        // Circular reference found
        try {
          // If this value does not reference a parent it can be deduped
         return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value));
        }
        catch (err) {
          // discard key if value cannot be deduped
         return;
        }
      }
      // Store value in our set
      cache.add(value);
    }
    return value;
  });
};
```

Comment: For deeply nested objects with circular references, try stringifyDeep => https://github.com/ORESoftware/safe-stringify

Comment: It's possibly that the Set implementation just uses an array and indexOf under the hood, but I haven't confirmed that.

Comment: This is removing parent nodes having child nodes even with different values - 
eg - `{"a":{"b":{"a":"d"}}}` and even removing nodes having empty object {}

Comment: Can you show an example of that Sandip? create a gist.github.com or whatnot

Comment: Excellent !!! First (from top, but checked 2-3 function solutions only) working solution here under node.js and Fission ;-) - libraries hanged-up.

Answer (score 26):

I'd recommend checking out [json-stringify-safe](https://github.com/isaacs/json-stringify-safe) from @isaacs-- it's used in NPM.

> BTW- if you're not using Node.js, you can just copy and paste lines 4-27 from the [relevant part of the source code](https://github.com/isaacs/json-stringify-safe/blob/02cfafd45f06d076ac4bf0dd28be6738a07a72f9/stringify.js#L4).

To install:

```
$ npm install json-stringify-safe --save
```

To use:

```
// Require the thing
var stringify = require('json-stringify-safe');

// Take some nasty circular object
var theBigNasty = {
  a: "foo",
  b: theBigNasty
};

// Then clean it up a little bit
var sanitized = JSON.parse(stringify(theBigNasty));
```

This yields:

```
{
  a: 'foo',
  b: '[Circular]'
}
```

> Note that, just like with the vanilla JSON.stringify function as @Rob W mentioned, you can also customize the sanitization behavior by passing in a "replacer" function as the second argument to `stringify()`.  If you find yourself needing a simple example of how to do this, I just wrote a custom replacer which coerces errors, regexps, and functions into human-readable strings [here](https://github.com/node-machine/rttc/blob/master/lib/helpers/validate-recursive.js#L316).

Comment: I like this solution because it solves the problem with fewer limitations than others. It avoids: 1) only working on NodeJS, 2) removing duplicates not just cycles, 3) outputting JSON with non-standard overall structure. It's also packaged nicely on npm, but with nice and short source code (allowing simple copy-paste).

Answer (score 14):

For future googlers searching for a solution to this problem when you *don't* know the keys of all circular references, you could use a wrapper around the JSON.stringify function to rule out circular references. See an example script at https://gist.github.com/4653128.

The solution essentially boils down to keeping a reference to previously printed objects in an array, and checking that in a replacer function before returning a value. It's more constrictive than only ruling out circular references, because it also rules out ever printing an object twice, one of the side affects of which is to avoid circular references.

Example wrapper:

```
function stringifyOnce(obj, replacer, indent){
    var printedObjects = [];
    var printedObjectKeys = [];

    function printOnceReplacer(key, value){
        var printedObjIndex = false;
        printedObjects.forEach(function(obj, index){
            if(obj===value){
                printedObjIndex = index;
            }
        });

        if(printedObjIndex && typeof(value)=="object"){
            return "(see " + value.constructor.name.toLowerCase() + " with key " + printedObjectKeys[printedObjIndex] + ")";
        }else{
            var qualifiedKey = key || "(empty key)";
            printedObjects.push(value);
            printedObjectKeys.push(qualifiedKey);
            if(replacer){
                return replacer(key, value);
            }else{
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
    return JSON.stringify(obj, printOnceReplacer, indent);
}
```

Comment: Nice code. You have a silly error though, you write `if(printedObjIndex)` while you should write `if(printedObjIndex==false)` because `index` can also be `0` which is translated to `false` unless you explicitly state otherwise.

Comment: @guymograbi Don't you mean `===`? `0 == false` is `true`, `0 === false` is `false`. ;^) But I'd rather not initialize `printedObjIndex` to false, as then you can check against `undefined` so that you're (well, Trindaz's) not mixing metaphors as strangely.

Comment: @ruffin nice catch. yes obviously, always use hard equality and jshint to catch such silly mistakes.

Answer (score 5):

```
var a={b:"b"};
a.a=a;
JSON.stringify(preventCircularJson(a));
```

evaluates to:

```
"{"b":"b","a":"CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_REMOVED"}"
```

with the function:

```
/**
 * Traverses a javascript object, and deletes all circular values
 * @param source object to remove circular references from
 * @param censoredMessage optional: what to put instead of censored values
 * @param censorTheseItems should be kept null, used in recursion
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function preventCircularJson(source, censoredMessage, censorTheseItems) {
    //init recursive value if this is the first call
    censorTheseItems = censorTheseItems || [source];
    //default if none is specified
    censoredMessage = censoredMessage || "CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_REMOVED";
    //values that have allready apeared will be placed here:
    var recursiveItems = {};
    //initaite a censored clone to return back
    var ret = {};
    //traverse the object:
    for (var key in source) {
        var value = source[key]
        if (typeof value == "object") {
            //re-examine all complex children again later:
            recursiveItems[key] = value;
        } else {
            //simple values copied as is
            ret[key] = value;
        }
    }
    //create list of values to censor:
    var censorChildItems = [];
    for (var key in recursiveItems) {
        var value = source[key];
        //all complex child objects should not apear again in children:
        censorChildItems.push(value);
    }
    //censor all circular values
    for (var key in recursiveItems) {
        var value = source[key];
        var censored = false;
        censorTheseItems.forEach(function (item) {
            if (item === value) {
                censored = true;
            }
        });
        if (censored) {
            //change circular values to this
            value = censoredMessage;
        } else {
            //recursion:
            value = preventCircularJson(value, censoredMessage, censorChildItems.concat(censorTheseItems));
        }
        ret[key] = value

    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Works, but is substantially more verbose than it could be.

Answer (score 5):

This solution fixes the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/how-can-i-print-a-circular-structure-in-a-json-like-format#comment37945084_11616993) reported by [user2451227](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2451227/user2451227) on [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/how-can-i-print-a-circular-structure-in-a-json-like-format#answer-11616993) (`when o = {}; JSON.stringify([o, o], getCircularReplacer())`).

```js
function newCircularReplacer () {
  const seenValues = []
  return circularReplacer

  function circularReplacer (key, value) {
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null && Object.keys(value).length) {
      const stackSize = seenValues.length
      if (stackSize) {
        for (let n = stackSize - 1; seenValues[n][key] !== value; --n) seenValues.pop() // Clean up expired references
        if (seenValues.includes(value)) return '[Circular]'
      }
      seenValues.push(value)
    }
    return value
  }
}

let o = {a: 1}
o.b = o // Circular reference
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(o, newCircularReplacer()) // {a:1,b:[Circular]} ✅
)

o = {}
const notCircularReference = [o, o]
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(notCircularReference, newCircularReplacer()) // [{},{}] ✅ (NOT circular reference)
)
```

Comment: How does answering a question with a link to the accepted answer of the same question help?

Comment: @AdamYost; The mentioned answer had an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/how-can-i-print-a-circular-structure-in-a-json-like-format#comment37945084_11616993). This answer resolves it.

Answer (score 4):

Use the JSON.stringify method with a replacer. Read this documentation for more information. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836459%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

```
var obj = {
  a: "foo",
  b: obj
}

var replacement = {"b":undefined};

alert(JSON.stringify(obj,replacement));
```

Figure out a way to populate the replacement array with cyclic references. You can use the typeof method to find if an the property is of type 'object' ( reference ) and an exact equality check ( === ) to verify circular reference.

Comment: This might only work in IE (considering the fact that MSDN is documentation from Microsoft, and Microsoft creates IE). In Firefox/Chrome, http://jsfiddle.net/ppmaW/ generates the circular reference error. FYI: `var obj = {foo:obj}` does **not** create a circular reference. Instead, it creates an object whose `foo` attribute refers to the previous value of `obj` (`undefined` if not previously defined, declared because of `var obj`).

Comment: Yes, this doesn't work in Chrome.  It simply outputs "b", rather than any of the other values in "obj".

Answer (score 4):

If

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
```

results in a

> TypeError: cyclic object value

Then you may want to print like this:

```
var output = '';
for (property in object) {
  output += property + ': ' + object[property]+'; ';
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Maybe because it only prints one level?

Comment: VERY SIMPLE i upvoted this because it worked for me right out of the box in chrome. EXCELLENT

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but I'd like to suggest an NPM package I've created called [smart-circular](https://github.com/Keenpoint/smart-circular), which works differently from the other ways proposed. It's specially useful if you're using *big and deep objects*.

Some features are:

- Replacing circular references or simply repeated structures inside the object by the path leading to its first occurrence (not just the string *[circular]*);
- By looking for circularities in a breadth-first search, the package ensures this path is as small as possible, which is important when dealing with very big and deep objects, where the paths can get annoyingly long and difficult to follow (the custom replacement in JSON.stringify does a DFS);
- Allows personalised replacements, handy to simplify or ignore less important parts of the object;
- Finally, the paths are written exactly in the way necessary to access the field referenced, which can help you debugging.

Comment: This is nice, although it's removing duplicates as well, not just circular links. (well, if you define "circular" as meaning that doing a depth-first recursion, without safeguards, would result in a call-stack going over the same entry multiple/infinite times) Has a use, but not what some would define as "circular" (ie. causing infinite recursion).

Answer (score 3):

The second argument to JSON.stringify() *also* allows you to specify an array of key names that should be preserved from every object it encounters within your data. This may not work for all use cases, but is a much simpler solution.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

```js
var obj = {
    a: "foo",
    b: this
}

var json = JSON.stringify(obj, ['a']);
console.log(json);
// {"a":"foo"}
```

**Note:** Strangely, the object definition from OP does not throw a circular reference error in the latest Chrome or Firefox. The definition in this answer was modified so that it *did* throw an error.

---

Answer (score 2):

I found [circular-json library on github](https://github.com/WebReflection/circular-json) and it worked well for my problem.

Some good features I found useful:

- Supports multi-platform usage but I only tested it with node.js so far.
- API is same so all you need to do is include and use it as a JSON replacement.
- It have it's own parsing method so you can convert the 'circular' serialized data back to object.

Comment: This library threw an error for me so I have to look for another.  ERROR TypeError: toISOString is not a function
    at String.toJSON (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:1:3458)
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at Object.stringifyRecursion [as stringify] (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:258450:15)

Comment: @MarkEllul I've written the comment in 2015 and if I'll see a better alternative I'll post it here with an edit. I still end up the same issue in daily work occasionally and I usually prefer my own manual functions in a recursive manner with a proper/safe inspection. I would suggest checking out functional programming practices if you are unfamiliar, usually, it's easing up this kind of recursive operations as being less tricky and more reliable.

Comment: Also getting "toISOString is not a function" trying to stringify an event and re-send it in a cypress test

Comment: Yeah, it was working fine back in 2013. Need to update

Answer (score 2):

To update the answer of overriding the way JSON works (probably not recommended, but super simple), don't use `circular-json` (it's deprecated). Instead, use the successor, flatted:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatted

Borrowed from the old answer above from @user1541685 , but replaced with the new one:

`npm i --save flatted`

then in your js file

```
const CircularJSON = require('flatted');
const json = CircularJSON.stringify(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will fail for circular reference:

```
    JSON.stringify(circularReference);
// TypeError: cyclic object value
```

Use the below code:

```
 const getCircularReplacer = () => {
  const seen = new WeakSet();
  return (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
      if (seen.has(value)) {
        return;
      }
      seen.add(value);
    }
    return value;
  };
};

JSON.stringify(circularReference, getCircularReplacer());
```

Comment: This remove all object used 2 times or more, not only references

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this problem like this:

```
var util = require('util');

// Our circular object
var obj = {foo: {bar: null}, a:{a:{a:{a:{a:{a:{a:{hi: 'Yo!'}}}}}}}};
obj.foo.bar = obj;

// Generate almost valid JS object definition code (typeof string)
var str = util.inspect(b, {depth: null});

// Fix code to the valid state (in this example it is not required, but my object was huge and complex, and I needed this for my case)
str = str
    .replace(/<Buffer[ \w\.]+>/ig, '"buffer"')
    .replace(/\[Function]/ig, 'function(){}')
    .replace(/\[Circular]/ig, '"Circular"')
    .replace(/\{ \[Function: ([\w]+)]/ig, '{ $1: function $1 () {},')
    .replace(/\[Function: ([\w]+)]/ig, 'function $1(){}')
    .replace(/(\w+): ([\w :]+GMT\+[\w \(\)]+),/ig, '$1: new Date("$2"),')
    .replace(/(\S+): ,/ig, '$1: null,');

// Create function to eval stringifyed code
var foo = new Function('return ' + str + ';');

// And have fun
console.log(JSON.stringify(foo(), null, 4));
```

Comment: This pretty much worked for me but it seems like classes were being represented like `_class: ClassName { data: "here" }`, so I added the following rule `.replace(/(\w+) {/g, '{ __ClassName__: "$1", ')`. In my case I was trying to see what an http request object looked like.

Answer (score 1):

Although this has been answered sufficiently, you could also explicitly delete the property in question before stringification using the `delete` operator.

```
delete obj.b; 
const jsonObject = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

[delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

this will remove the need to build or maintain complex logic to remove circular references.

Answer (score 1):

```
function myStringify(obj, maxDeepLevel = 2) {
  if (obj === null) {
    return 'null';
  }
  if (obj === undefined) {
    return 'undefined';
  }
  if (maxDeepLevel < 0 || typeof obj !== 'object') {
    return obj.toString();
  }
  return Object
    .entries(obj)
    .map(x => x[0] + ': ' + myStringify(x[1], maxDeepLevel - 1))
    .join('\r\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that:

- removes cycles *only* (and not *all* duplicate object references, as do most of the solutions posted here so far),
- is not unnecessarily verbose,
- is fast,
- does not require any library dependency.

```
function replaceCycles(obj, replacement = undefined, seen = new WeakSet()) {
  if (typeof obj === 'object')
    if (seen.has(obj))
      return replacement 
    else {
      seen.add(obj)
      const newObj = {}
      for (const key in obj)
        newObj[key] = replaceCycles(obj[key], replacement, seen)
      seen.delete(obj)
      return newObj
    }
  else
    return obj
}
```

Usage:

```
const a = {
  b: 'v1',
  c: {
    d: 'v2'
  }
}

a.e = a.c
a.c.f = a.c

console.log(JSON.stringify(replaceCycles(a, '[CYCLE]')))
```

Output:

```
"{'b':'v1','c':{'d':'v2','f':'[CYCLE]'},'e':{'d':'v2','f':'[CYCLE]'}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

an other solution for resolving this issue with these kind of objects is that using this library

https://github.com/ericmuyser/stringy

its simple and you can in a few simple step solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other answers I end up with the following code. It works pretty well with circular references, objects with custom constructors.

From the given object to be serialized,

- Cache all the object you come across while traversing the object and assign each of them a unique hashID (an auto-incrementing number also works)
- Once a circular reference is found mark that field in the new object as circular and store the hashID of the original object as an attribute.

**Github Link** - [DecycledJSON](https://github.com/studiobytestorm/DecycledJSON/)

```
DJSHelper = {};
DJSHelper.Cache = [];
DJSHelper.currentHashID = 0;
DJSHelper.ReviveCache = [];

// DOES NOT SERIALIZE FUNCTION
function DJSNode(name, object, isRoot){
    this.name = name;
    // [ATTRIBUTES] contains the primitive fields of the Node
    this.attributes = {};

    // [CHILDREN] contains the Object/Typed fields of the Node
    // All [CHILDREN] must be of type [DJSNode]
    this.children = []; //Array of DJSNodes only

    // If [IS-ROOT] is true reset the Cache and currentHashId
    // before encoding
    isRoot = typeof isRoot === 'undefined'? true:isRoot;
    this.isRoot = isRoot;
    if(isRoot){
        DJSHelper.Cache = [];
        DJSHelper.currentHashID = 0;

        // CACHE THE ROOT
        object.hashID = DJSHelper.currentHashID++;
        DJSHelper.Cache.push(object);
    }

    for(var a in object){
        if(object.hasOwnProperty(a)){
            var val = object[a];

            if (typeof val === 'object') {
                // IF OBJECT OR NULL REF.

                /***************************************************************************/
                // DO NOT REMOVE THE [FALSE] AS THAT WOULD RESET THE [DJSHELPER.CACHE]
                // AND THE RESULT WOULD BE STACK OVERFLOW
                /***************************************************************************/
                if(val !== null) {
                    if (DJSHelper.Cache.indexOf(val) === -1) {
                        // VAL NOT IN CACHE
                        // ADD THE VAL TO CACHE FIRST -> BEFORE DOING RECURSION
                        val.hashID = DJSHelper.currentHashID++;
                        //console.log("Assigned", val.hashID, "to", a);
                        DJSHelper.Cache.push(val);

                        if (!(val instanceof Array)) {
                            // VAL NOT AN [ARRAY]
                            try {
                                this.children.push(new DJSNode(a, val, false));
                            } catch (err) {
                                console.log(err.message, a);
                                throw err;
                            }
                        } else {
                            // VAL IS AN [ARRAY]
                            var node = new DJSNode(a, {
                                array: true,
                                hashID: val.hashID // HashID of array
                            }, false);
                            val.forEach(function (elem, index) {
                                node.children.push(new DJSNode("elem", {val: elem}, false));
                            });
                            this.children.push(node);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // VAL IN CACHE
                        // ADD A CYCLIC NODE WITH HASH-ID
                        this.children.push(new DJSNode(a, {
                            cyclic: true,
                            hashID: val.hashID
                        }, false));
                    }
                }else{
                    // PUT NULL AS AN ATTRIBUTE
                    this.attributes[a] = 'null';
                }
            } else if (typeof val !== 'function') {
                // MUST BE A PRIMITIVE
                // ADD IT AS AN ATTRIBUTE
                this.attributes[a] = val;
            }
        }
    }

    if(isRoot){
        DJSHelper.Cache = null;
    }
    this.constructorName = object.constructor.name;
}
DJSNode.Revive = function (xmlNode, isRoot) {
    // Default value of [isRoot] is True
    isRoot = typeof isRoot === 'undefined'?true: isRoot;
    var root;
    if(isRoot){
        DJSHelper.ReviveCache = []; //Garbage Collect
    }
    if(window[xmlNode.constructorName].toString().indexOf('[native code]') > -1 ) {
        // yep, native in the browser
        if(xmlNode.constructorName == 'Object'){
            root = {};
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }else {
        eval('root = new ' + xmlNode.constructorName + "()");
    }

    //CACHE ROOT INTO REVIVE-CACHE
    DJSHelper.ReviveCache[xmlNode.attributes.hashID] = root;

    for(var k in xmlNode.attributes){
        // PRIMITIVE OR NULL REF FIELDS
        if(xmlNode.attributes.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            var a = xmlNode.attributes[k];
            if(a == 'null'){
                root[k] = null;
            }else {
                root[k] = a;
            }
        }
    }

    xmlNode.children.forEach(function (value) {
        // Each children is an [DJSNode]
        // [Array]s are stored as [DJSNode] with an positive Array attribute
        // So is value

        if(value.attributes.array){
            // ITS AN [ARRAY]
            root[value.name] = [];
            value.children.forEach(function (elem) {
                root[value.name].push(elem.attributes.val);
            });
            //console.log("Caching", value.attributes.hashID);
            DJSHelper.ReviveCache[value.attributes.hashID] = root[value.name];
        }else if(!value.attributes.cyclic){
            // ITS AN [OBJECT]
            root[value.name] = DJSNode.Revive(value, false);
            //console.log("Caching", value.attributes.hashID);
            DJSHelper.ReviveCache[value.attributes.hashID] = root[value.name];
        }
    });

    // [SEPARATE ITERATION] TO MAKE SURE ALL POSSIBLE
    // [CYCLIC] REFERENCES ARE CACHED PROPERLY
    xmlNode.children.forEach(function (value) {
        // Each children is an [DJSNode]
        // [Array]s are stored as [DJSNode] with an positive Array attribute
        // So is value

        if(value.attributes.cyclic){
            // ITS AND [CYCLIC] REFERENCE
            root[value.name] = DJSHelper.ReviveCache[value.attributes.hashID];
        }
    });

    if(isRoot){
        DJSHelper.ReviveCache = null; //Garbage Collect
    }
    return root;
};

DecycledJSON = {};
DecycledJSON.stringify = function (obj) {
    return JSON.stringify(new DJSNode("root", obj));
};
DecycledJSON.parse = function (json, replacerObject) {
    // use the replacerObject to get the null values
    return DJSNode.Revive(JSON.parse(json));
};
DJS = DecycledJSON;
```

**Example Usage 1:**

```
var obj = {
    id:201,
    box: {
        owner: null,
        key: 'storm'
    },
    lines:[
        'item1',
        23
    ]
};

console.log(obj); // ORIGINAL

// SERIALIZE AND THEN PARSE
var jsonObj = DJS.stringify(obj);
console.log(DJS.parse(jsonObj));
```

**Example Usage 2:**

```
// PERSON OBJECT

function Person() {
    this.name = null;
    this.child = null;
    this.dad = null;
    this.mom = null;
}
var Dad = new Person();
Dad.name = 'John';
var Mom = new Person();
Mom.name = 'Sarah';
var Child = new Person();
Child.name = 'Kiddo';

Dad.child = Mom.child = Child;
Child.dad = Dad;
Child.mom = Mom;

console.log(Child); // ORIGINAL

// SERIALIZE AND THEN PARSE
var jsonChild = DJS.stringify(Child);
console.log(DJS.parse(jsonChild));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old and has lots of great answers but I post this answer because of it's new flavor *(es5+)*

```js
Object.defineProperties(JSON, {
  refStringify: {
    value: function(obj) {

      let objMap = new Map();
      let stringified = JSON.stringify(obj,
        function(key, value) {

          // only for objects
          if (typeof value == 'object') {
            // If has the value then return a reference to it
            if (objMap.has(value))
              return objMap.get(value);

            objMap.set(value, `ref${objMap.size + 1}`);
          }
          return value;
        });
      return stringified;
    }
  },
  refParse: {
    value: function(str) {

      let parsed = JSON.parse(str);
      let objMap = _createObjectMap(parsed);
      objMap.forEach((value, key) => _replaceKeyWithObject(value, key));
      return parsed;
    }
  },
});

// *************************** Example
let a = {
  b: 32,
  c: {
    get a() {
        return a;
      },
      get c() {
        return a.c;
      }
  }
};
let stringified = JSON.refStringify(a);
let parsed = JSON.refParse(stringified, 2);
console.log(parsed, JSON.refStringify(parsed));
// *************************** /Example

// *************************** Helper
function _createObjectMap(obj) {

  let objMap = new Map();
  JSON.stringify(obj, (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value == 'object') {
      if (objMap.has(value))
        return objMap.get(value);
      objMap.set(value, `ref${objMap.size + 1}`);

    }
    return value;
  });
  return objMap;
}

function _replaceKeyWithObject(key, obj, replaceWithObject = obj) {

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {

    let val = obj[k];
    if (val == key)
      return (obj[k] = replaceWithObject);
    if (typeof val == 'object' && val != replaceWithObject)
      _replaceKeyWithObject(key, val, replaceWithObject);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var obj = {
    a: "foo",
    b: obj
};

var circular_replacer = (value) => {
    var seen = [];
    if (value != null && typeof value == "object") {
        if (seen.indexOf(value) >= 0) return;
        seen.push(value);
    }
    return value;
};

obj = circular_replacer(obj);
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be, like, few more lines of code after the `seen.push(value)` =-D? Like `for (var key in value) {value[key] = circular_replacer(value[key]);}`

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on edit and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21661015)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the JSON parser library: [treedoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/treedoc). it supports circular references and also dedupes the repeated objects with references.

`yarn add treedoc`

```
import {TD} from 'treedoc'
TD.stringify(obj);
```

If you want more customization

```
import {TD, TDEncodeOption} from 'treedoc'

const opt = new TDEncodeOption();
opt.coderOption.setShowType(true).setShowFunction(true);
opt.jsonOption.setIndentFactor(2);
return TD.stringify(obj, opt);
```

The generated JSON file can be viewed by the viewer http://treedoc.org, which supports the navigation through JSON node references.

*[shameless plug] I'm the author of this library*

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers in this thread are catered to use with `JSON.stringify` specifically -- they do not show how to actually remove circular-references in the original object-tree. (well, short of calling `JSON.parse` again afterward -- which requires reassignment, and has a higher performance impact)

For removing circular-references from the source object-tree, you can use a function such as this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63952549/2441655

These general-purpose circular-reference-remover functions can then be used to make subsequent calls to circular-reference-sensitive functions (like `JSON.stringify`) safe:

```
const objTree = {normalProp: true};
objTree.selfReference = objTree;
RemoveCircularLinks(objTree); // without this line, the JSON.stringify call errors
console.log(JSON.stringify(objTree));
```

Answer (score 0):

We use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) for our data processing and it might be a viable solution here. This is how it could work (also pruning arrays correctly)

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import objectScan from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/object-scan@18.1.2/lib/index.min.js';

const prune = (data) => objectScan(['**'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ isCircular, parent, property }) => {
    if (isCircular) {
      if (Array.isArray(parent)) {
        parent.splice(property, 1);
      } else {
        delete parent[property];
      }
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },
  breakFn: ({ isCircular }) => isCircular === true
})(data);

const obj = { a: 'foo', c: [0] };
obj.b = obj;
obj.c.push(obj);
console.log(obj);
// => <ref *1> { a: 'foo', c: [ 0, [Circular *1] ], b: [Circular *1] }

console.log(prune(obj)); // returns circular counts
// => 2

console.log(obj);
// => { a: 'foo', c: [ 0 ] }
</script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Answer (score 0):

I created following method for my LoggingUtilities class.
Following method takes source and target objects, and assign source to target by given maxLevel.

```
  static assignObjectByLevel(
    sourceObject: any,
    targetObject: any,
    currentLevel: number = 0,
    maxLevel: number = 3,
    showUndefinedValues = false
  ): any {
    if (currentLevel >= maxLevel) {
      return;
    }

    const objQueue = [];
    for (const key in sourceObject) {
      if (sourceObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const value = sourceObject[key];
        if (typeof value === "object") {
          objQueue.push({ key, value });
        } else {
          targetObject[key] = value;
        }
      } else {
        if (showUndefinedValues) {
          targetObject[key] = "undefined/null";
        }
      }
    }

    while (objQueue.length > 0) {
      const objVal = objQueue.pop();
      currentLevel++;
      targetObject[objVal.key] = {};
      this.assignObjectByLevel(
        objVal.value,
        targetObject[objVal.key],
        currentLevel,
        maxLevel,
        false
      );
    }
  }
```

Usage Example:

```
   const logObjParam = {
      level1: "value1",
      level2: {
        value2: "value2",
        level3: {
          value3: "value3",
          level4: {
            value4: " value4",
            level5: {
              value5: " value5",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    };

 let logObj = {};
 this.assignObjectByLevel(logObjParam, logObj);
```

Result:

```
{
  "level1": "value1",
  "level2": {
    "value2": "value2",
    "level3": {
      "value3": "value3",
      "level4": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

superserial fully serializes JavaScript objects.

https://github.com/denostack/superserial

Usage:

```ts
const serializer = new Serializer();

const nodes = [{ self: null as any, siblings: [] as any[] }, {
  self: null as any,
  siblings: [] as any[],
}];
nodes[0].self = nodes[0];
nodes[0].siblings = nodes;
nodes[1].self = nodes[1];
nodes[1].siblings = nodes;

const serialized = serializer.serialize(nodes);

console.log(serialized);
```

output:

```
[$1,$2];{"self":$1,"siblings":$0};{"self":$2,"siblings":$0}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I carefully red all the other excellent answers to this question, but none of them satisfies me for two reasons:

1. some of them disrupts the original object;
2. if I cut/paste the payload in a source code, it is no equivalent to the original object.

To solve all the three problem at once (the one in the question plus the other two I had) I wrote [next-json](https://github.com/iccicci/next-json#readme).

- It offers an interface analogue to the JSON one.
- The payload can be cut/pasted in a source code to reproduce the original object.
- It exposes polyfill for express and `fetch`.

Basic usage.

```js
import { NJSON } from "next-json";

const obj = { test: Infinity };
const set = new Set();
const arr = [NaN, obj, set];

set.add(obj);
set.add(arr);
arr.push(arr);

console.log(NJSON.stringify(arr));
// ((A,B)=>{B.push(A,new Set([A,B]),B);return B})({"test":Infinity},[NaN])
```

With polyfill.

Server side:

```js
import express from "express";
import { expressNJSON } from "next-json";

const app = express();

app.use(expressNJSON()); // install the polyfill
app.all("/mirror", (req, res) => res.njson(req.body)); // there is an 'n' more than usual
app.listen(3000);
```

Client side:

```js
import { NJSON, fetchNJSON } from "next-json";

fetchNJSON(); // install the polyfill

const payload = { infinity: Infinity };
payload.circular = payload;

const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/mirror", {
  body: NJSON.stringify(payload), // there is an 'N' more than usual
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/njson" }, // there is an 'n' more than usual
  method: "POST"
});
const body = await response.njson(); // there is an 'n' more than usual
```

Here `payload` deep equals `payload.circular`, which deep equals `body`, which deep equals `body.circular`, which deep equals `req.body` in server side, which deep equals `req.body.circular` in server side.