# Finding a circular object in the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, circular-reference, cyclic-reference

I am writing a script using jQuery for loading some content into my page.
At runtime nothing happens. I get this error when inspecting Firebug console:

```
TypeError: cyclic object value  
data: JSON.stringify({ columnName: _columnName })
```

Here is the code (placed inside <Head>):

```
<Script>
function changeContent(_columnName) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetContent")',
            data: JSON.stringify({ columnName: _columnName }),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        }).done(function (resp) {
            CKEDITOR.instances.text.setData(resp.Text);
        }).fail(function () {
            alert("Error");
        });
    }
    $(function () {
        $("#side-content").bind('click', { a: "side" }, changeContent);
    });
</Script>
```

I used the tip here: [Detecting and fixing circular references in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962018/detecting-and-fixing-circular-references-in-javascript) but could not find any circular relations!!!

Any point on saving my life would be so greatly appreciated.
- Kamran

Comment: You really want to send the DOM Event object via AJAX?

Comment: To expand on what Dogbert is saying, try `function changeContent(e, _columnName) { ...` (To see what's wrong with your current version, add `console.log(_columnName)` as the first line of the function.)

Comment: @Kamran look at what the object is (nnnnnn's comment) and you'll likely answer that for yourself.

Comment: @Kamran Perhaps you can explain why you want to send the complete DOM event object to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved and well understood**

The main part of the problem was I did not know that **the argument of the handler is DOM event.** I thought that `_columnName` will receive event data which was wrong. It is DOM event in fact.

The working code follows:

```
<script>
    function changeContent(event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetHomeColumnContent")',
            data: JSON.stringify({ columnName: event.data.a }),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        }).done(function (resp) {
            CKEDITOR.instances.text.setData(resp.Text);
        }).fail(function () {
            alert("Error");
        });
    }
    $(function () {
        $("#side-content").bind('click', { a: 'side' }, changeContent);
    });
</script>
```

**And about the cyclic value:** DOM elements are cyclic in nature because every DOM element has a reference to its parent, and in turn every parent has references to its children, so a cyclic structure.

Thanks to all friends for their times: @Dogbert, @nnnnnn, @AD7six, @Xotic750 ;-)