# trying to stringify sails.config.global, circular structure error

Tags: node.js, sails.js, stringify

I'm getting an error when trying to stringify a global variable in sails:
TypeError: converting circular structure to JSON.

I know what the error means, but the question is, what's happening that's causing there to be a circular reference.  And, why does it happen to my custom variable?

Then the next question is: how can I stringify the object the way I created it in globals.js?

In config/globals.js:

```
module.exports.globals = {
    mystuff: {
        Url: "http://localhost:8080",
        APIKey: "2bb67717b99a37e92e59003f93625c9b"
    }
}
```

In a hook initialize:

```
module.exports = function (sails) { 
   return {

        initialize: function(cb) {
           var str = JSON.stringify(sails.config.globals.mystuff);
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped identify circular culprits:
[Detecting and fixing circular references in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962018/detecting-and-fixing-circular-references-in-javascript)

Another portion of the app was injecting objects into the globals.