# Breezejs Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: json, knockout.js, breeze, circular-reference

I have an ASP.Net MVC SPA using the Hot Towel template i.e. breezejs, knockout, entity framework (code first), durandal etc.

In my EF model I have a class named "Section" that has a self referencing association.  Each section belongs to a "Document" and each Section also has a collection of "Items":

```
    public class Section : CommonBase
    {
        ...

        public Guid DocumentId { get; set; }
        public Document Document { get; set; }

        ...

        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

        public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }
        public Section Parent { get; set; }

        public List<Section> Children { get; set; }

        ...
   }

   public class Item : CommonBase
   {
       ...

       public Guid SectionId { get; set; }
       public Section Section { get; set; }

       ...
   }
```

I load the "Sections" and "Items" when I load the documents via a Breeze query and a BreezeController method:

```
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from(model.entitySets.document)
                              .where(predicate)
                              .expand("sections.items.cloudDriveFile, sections.cloudDriveFile")
                              .orderBy(model.orderByClauses.document);

    return _contextProvider.Context.Documents.Where(x => x.OrganisationId == currentUser.OrganisationId);
```

If I edit and save a "Section" without loading any "Items" then all works OK.  However when I try to edit and save a section that has "Items" - and I have loaded those "Items" (either using an Include in the BreezeController or an Expand in javascript) - then I get the following error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON "

I am saving using a simple call to manager.saveChanges().

Is there some technique or pattern that I should be implementing to avoid this circular reference error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation I found that this same problem was occurring whenever I tried to save changes to an object that had loaded a related collection (i.e. the contents of a navigation property), where the objects in the collection then had a reference back to the parent.  I tracked the error down to the following line in breeze.debug.js (version 1.3.5):

```
var bundle = JSON.stringify(saveBundle);
```

I found that if I replaced this line with the following (as per [JSON.stringify, avoid TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)) then the error no longer occurred:

```
    var cache = [];
    var bundle = JSON.stringify(saveBundle, function (key, value) {
        if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
            if (cache.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
                // Circular reference found, discard key
                return;
            }
            // Store value in our collection
            cache.push(value);
        }
        return value;
    });
    cache = null; // Enable garbage collection
```

While this fixes my current issue I feel that there must be an alternative approach to this - surely I cannot be the only one trying to save changes in this scenario.

Comment: I thought I had the same problem, but this code doesn't fix my problem. Any idea?

Comment: As it turns out, cache.indexOf(value) !== -1 is never true in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your EF model is **Code First** or **Database First**, but if **Code First** I didn't see any attributes on your entityModel having to do with defining the ForeignKey property. If **Database First** make sure that foreign key associations are enabled. The following links may provide more information: [Navigation properties](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/navigation-properties), [Server side model](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/server-side-model-0)

Comment: It is Code First.  Are you saying that I have to specifically add the [ForeignKey] attribute to ParentId and DocumentId in the model excerpt shown in my question?  I assumed that using the Code First naming conventions (i.e. DocumentId and Document) was enough.  This is the only problem that I have had with navigation properties i.e. the ones that are not self referencing seem to be working OK.

Comment: In general, conventions should be enough, but it's possible that EF cannot determine fk's properly without [ForeignKey] attributes when a self referencing  constraint is involved. Certainly worth a try.

Comment: I've added in all the ForeignKey attributes and that has not helped.  I have been able to narrow things down a bit more and have amended my question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to fix this issue by eager loading the Children instead.

Remove the virtual from public virtual List Children

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - but this did not help.