# How to pass API url JSON http.get res.json(data) using express.js

Tags: json, node.js, http, express

I am trying to send a JSON object back to my client using a websites API and am getting the following error.

```
var body = JSON.stringify(obj, replacer, spaces);

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
at Object,stringify (native)
```

Here is my code

```
app.get('/api/test', function(req, res){
   http.get('http://api.biblia.com/v1/bible/content/LEB.txt.json?passage=John3.16&key=fd37d8f28e95d3be8cb4fbc37e15e18e', function(data) {
       res.json(data);
   });
});
```

If I replace `data` with a simple JSON object {"test":"test"}. Everything works fine. Any help with understanding what is even occuring would be helpful. I am using an Express.js Node.js Angular.js stack. Thank you!

Comment: you should log the data you are getting back from the biblia api and make sure it's what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` variable in your callback is actually an instance of [http.IncomingMessage](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage), which is much more complex than just data. The error you're getting is because it has circular references, so you need to filter it out. There is [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json) that outlines this process using the code below:

```
var cache = [];
JSON.stringify(o, function(key, value) {
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
        if (cache.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
            // Circular reference found, discard key
            return;
        }
        // Store value in our collection
        cache.push(value);
    }
    return value;
});
cache = null; // Enable garbage collection
```