# Write objects into file with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io

I've searched all over stackoverflow / google for this, but can't seem to figure it out.

I'm scraping social media links of a given URL page, and the function returns an object with a list of URLs.

When I try to write this data into a different file, it outputs to the file as `[object Object]` instead of the expected: 
    [ 'https://twitter.com/#!/101Cookbooks',
    'http://www.facebook.com/101cookbooks'] 
as it does when I `console.log()` the results.

This is my sad attempt to read and write a file in Node, trying to read each line(the url) and input through a function call `request(line, gotHTML)`:

```
fs.readFileSync('./urls.txt').toString().split('\n').forEach(function (line){
    console.log(line); 
    var obj = request(line, gotHTML); 
    console.log(obj); 
    fs.writeFileSync('./data.json', obj , 'utf-8'); 
});
```

for reference -- the `gotHTML` function:

```
function gotHTML(err, resp, html){ 
    var social_ids = []; 

    if(err){
        return console.log(err); 
    } else if (resp.statusCode === 200){ 
        var parsedHTML = $.load(html); 

        parsedHTML('a').map(function(i, link){
            var href = $(link).attr('href');
            for(var i=0; i<socialurls.length; i++){
                if(socialurls[i].test(href) && social_ids.indexOf(href) < 0 ) {
                    social_ids.push(href); 
                }; 
            }; 
        })
    };

    return social_ids;
};
```

Comment: `[object Object]` is an object `toString`. If you want the representation of the object, use `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Be careful with `JSON.stringify`. With arrays, you're safe, but when objects have circular references it will fail ([see this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11616993/151445)). The `util` module handles circular references.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`obj` is an array in your example.

**fs.writeFileSync(filename, data, [options])** requires either `String` or `Buffer` in the data parameter. [see docs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_filename_data_options).

Try to write the array in a string format:

```
// writes 'https://twitter.com/#!/101Cookbooks', 'http://www.facebook.com/101cookbooks'
fs.writeFileSync('./data.json', obj.join(',') , 'utf-8');
```

Or:

```
// writes ['https://twitter.com/#!/101Cookbooks', 'http://www.facebook.com/101cookbooks']
var util = require('util');
fs.writeFileSync('./data.json', util.inspect(obj) , 'utf-8');
```

edit: The reason you see the array in your example is because node's implementation of `console.log` doesn't just call `toString`, it calls `util.format` [see console.js source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/22c68fdc1dae40f0ed9c71a02f66e5b2c6353691/lib/console.js#L52)

Comment: If your object contains large arrays, this will not work as the inspect method will output something like "45000 more...]"

Answer (score 130):

Building on what deb2fast said I would also pass in a couple of extra parameters to JSON.stringify() to get it to pretty format:

```
fs.writeFileSync('./data.json', JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2) , 'utf-8');
```

The second param is an optional replacer function which you don't need in this case so `null` works.

The third param is the number of spaces to use for indentation. 2 and 4 seem to be popular choices.

Comment: it is going to cause circular dependency problem. two-way dependencies could not be converted to JSON.

Comment: The written text file is missing the newline character at the end of the file. Any way to fix this?

Comment: @friederbluemle - You could `+ '\n'` to that stringify() call to add that newline.

Comment: This one worked best for me cause using the accepted answer gave me the wrong result.

Answer (score 23):

If you're geting `[object object]` then use `JSON.stringify`

`fs.writeFile('./data.json', JSON.stringify(obj) , 'utf-8');`

It worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

In my experience JSON.stringify is slightly faster than util.inspect.
I had to save the result object of a DB2 query as a json file, The query returned an object of 92k rows, the conversion took very long to complete with util.inspect, so I did the following test by writing the same 1000 record object to a file with both methods.

1. JSON.Stringify

   ```
   fs.writeFile('./data.json', JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
   ```

Time: 3:57 (3 min 57 sec)

Result's format:

```
[
  {
    "PROB": "00001",
    "BO": "AXZ",
    "CNTRY": "649"
   },
  ...
]
```

2. util.inspect

   ```
   var util = require('util');
   fs.writeFile('./data.json', util.inspect(obj, false, 2, false));
   ```

Time: 4:12 (4 min 12 sec)

Result's format:

```
[ { PROB: '00001',
    BO: 'AXZ',
    CNTRY: '649' },
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Could you try doing `JSON.stringify(obj);`

Like this:

```
var stringify = JSON.stringify(obj);
fs.writeFileSync('./data.json', stringify, 'utf-8');
```

Answer (score 2):

Just incase anyone else stumbles across this, I use the fs-extra library in node and write javascript objects to a file like this:

```
const fse = require('fs-extra');
fse.outputJsonSync('path/to/output/file.json', objectToWriteToFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to `@Jim Schubert`'s and `@deb2fast`'s answers:

To be able to write out large `objects` of order which are than `~100 MB`, you'll need to use for...of as shown below and match to your requirements.

```js
const fsPromises = require('fs').promises;

const sampleData = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"};

const writeToFile = async () => {
  for (const dataObject of Object.keys(sampleData)) {
      console.log(sampleData[dataObject]);
      await fsPromises.appendFile( "out.json" , dataObject +": "+ JSON.stringify(sampleData[dataObject]));
  }
}

writeToFile();
```

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67699911/3152654 for full reference for `node.js` limits