# write a javascript object to a file in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I use Node to take a JS object (e.g. `var obj = {a: 1, b: 2}`) and create a file that contains that object?

For example, the following works:

```
var fs = require('fs')

fs.writeFile('./temp.js', 'var obj = {a: 1, b: 2}', function(err) {
  if(err) console.log(err)
  // creates a file containing: var obj = {a: 1, b: 2}
})
```

But this doesn't work:

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2}

fs.writeFile('./temp.js', obj, function(err) {
  if(err) console.log(err)
  // creates a file containing: [object Object]
})
```

**Update**: `JSON.stringify()` will create a JSON object (i.e. `{"a":1,"b":2}`) and not a Javascript object (i.e. `{a:1,b:2}`)

Comment: `JSON.stringify(object)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write objects into file with Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976567/write-objects-into-file-with-node-js)

Comment: search for how to stringify objects!

Comment: I don't believe stringify is the answer. This will create a JSON string (i.e. `{"a":1,"b":2}`) and not a JS object (i.e. `{a:1,b:2}`)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks Stephan Bijzitter for the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21976700/2102042)

My problem can be solved like so:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var util = require('util')
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2}

fs.writeFileSync('./temp.js', 'var obj = ' + util.inspect(obj) , 'utf-8')
```

This writes a file containing: `var obj = { a: 1, b: 2 }`

Comment: This is unfortunately not a proper answer, as `util.inspect` will truncate arrays and integers, and not result in the expected object.

Answer (score 3):

Its because of arguments that `writeFile` requires.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

It wants data to be  `<String> | <Buffer> | <Uint8Array>`

So your first example works because it's a string.

In order to make second work just use `JSON.stringify(obj)`;

Like this

```
fs.writeFile('file.txt', JSON.stringify(obj), callback)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const util = require('util')
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2}

fs.writeFileSync(
  './temp.js',
  util.formatWithOptions({compact: false}, 'var obj = %o', obj),
  'utf-8'
)
```

Formatted output:

```
// ./temp.js
var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) your object:

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2}

fs.writeFile('./temp.js', JSON.stringify(obj), function(err) {
  if(err) console.log(err)
})
```