# Writing JSON object to a JSON file with fs.writeFileSync

Tags: json, node.js, file, fs

I am trying to write a JSON object to a JSON file. The code executes without errors, but instead of the content of the object been written, all that gets written into the JSON file is:

```
[object Object]
```

This is the code that actually does the writing:

```
fs.writeFileSync('../data/phraseFreqs.json', output)
```

'output' is a JSON object, and the file already exists. Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: fs.writeFileSync('../data/phraseFreqs.json', JSON.stringify(output))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write objects into file with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976567/write-objects-into-file-with-node-js)

Answer (score 220, accepted):

You need to stringify the object.

```
fs.writeFileSync('../data/phraseFreqs.json', JSON.stringify(output));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, before answering a question, try to review the existing answer. If your answer has already been suggested, upvote that answer instead. See the [community guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for writing a good answer.

Comment: I like that this answers the question without opinions about whether or not to use synchronous vs async operations.

Comment: For readability purposes, you can use the space parameter of the JSON.stringify method:
`fs.writeFileSync('../data/phraseFreqs.json', JSON.stringify(output, null, 2));`
More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 54):

I don't think you should use the synchronous approach, asynchronously writing data to a file is better also stringify the `output` if it's an `object`.

Note: If `output` is a string, then specify the encoding and remember the `flag` options as well.:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const content = JSON.stringify(output);

fs.writeFile('/tmp/phraseFreqs.json', content, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

Added Synchronous method of writing data to a file, but please consider your use case. [Asynchronous vs synchronous execution, what does it really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const content = JSON.stringify(output);

fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/phraseFreqs.json', content);
```

Comment: If it's being done in a short script or something, synchronous is fine. If it's part of a server request or something, then it should be asynchronous.

Comment: Not necessarily, I/O bound processes should be made asynchronous, but depending on the short script complexity you might opt in for synchronous.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: User specifically asked for synchronous method

Comment: this is generating a empty object: `{}`

Comment: what do you have has `output` in `const content = JSON.stringify(output);` i.e. `const content = JSON.stringify({ 'hello': 'world' });`

Comment: Please stop saying async good. And implying sync bad. If you are worried about speed, your webpack should do that optimization for you. You are not an optimizer. Reason:  sync file writing is needed for json command-line tools. Which must close any files they have open before piping data to the next app in the chain.

Comment: Synchronous is completely fine. There's no reason it shouldn't be accepted and supported.

Answer (score 38):

Make the json human readable by passing a third argument to `stringify`:

```js
fs.writeFileSync('../data/phraseFreqs.json', JSON.stringify(output, null, 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

When sending data to a web server, the data has to be a string ([here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp)). You can convert a JavaScript object into a string with `JSON.stringify()`. 
[Here](http://tpcg.io/MtKtSb) is a working example:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var originalNote = {
  title: 'Meeting',
  description: 'Meeting John Doe at 10:30 am'
};

var originalNoteString = JSON.stringify(originalNote);

fs.writeFileSync('notes.json', originalNoteString);

var noteString = fs.readFileSync('notes.json');

var note = JSON.parse(noteString);

console.log(`TITLE: ${note.title} DESCRIPTION: ${note.description}`);
```

Hope it could help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation, using the version of `fs` that uses promises:

```
const fs = require('fs');

await fs.promises.writeFile('../data/phraseFreqs.json', JSON.stringify(output)); // UTF-8 is default
```