# How do I update the entries in package.json automatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I have `package.json` which is below

```
{
  "name": "b",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": ".eslintrc.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Now, I want to update `"name"` from `b` to `new-b`. How can I do that programmatically?
I tried `npm config set` command, but it does not update `package.json` file

Please let me know
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to use the CLI to modify the package properties, you should be able to use [the pkg command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-pkg). Though I seemed to be running into some issues with it on npm 7.5.4.

```
npm pkg set name new-b
```

**Edit**: Whelp turns out that this command was actually [added 2 weeks prior](https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.20.0) to this post, so you'll actually need at least npm version v7.20.0 to correctly run the command.

Comment: I think that's the issue. I logged a question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68583943/unknown-command-pkg-when-running-npm-command

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a JavaScript file, you can use the fs module to change the package.json files contents.

For example, you could have a build.js file which asks you which content to change and then uses fs to read the current file and overwrite it. Refer to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179037/writing-json-object-to-a-json-file-with-fs-writefilesync) for help using fs with JSON objects.