# Unknown command: "pkg" when running npm command

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am facing the issue in running this command

```
npm pkg set name=foo3
Unknown command: "pkg"

To see a list of supported npm commands, run:
  npm help
```

The [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-pkg) says that it is available in `7.x` release, yet it fails when I run it

My `npm` version is

```
➜  foo3 git:(master) npm -v
7.17.0
```

What am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

7.20.3 (latest as of this post) has `pkg` available

```sh
$ npm --version
7.20.3
$ npm pkg set name=testpkg
$ cat package.json
{
  "name": "testpkg",
...
```

```
npm i -g npm
```

To update to latest.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried and it worked

```
flakerimi$ npm pkg set name=foo3
flakerimi$ npm pkg get
{
  "name": "foo3",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Maybe it has to do with your version of NPM or npm installation, Can you reinstall it, try from stable source.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install -g npm` is working on my side

Answer (score 0):

To make sure it works for all users, this is what I am doing right now

```
npx -y npm@latest pkg set name=${repoName}
```