# How to save an object in a file using nodejs

Tags: node.js, stream, filestream, fs

My code is this:

```
fs.writeFile("file.bin", this, 'binary', function(err){
  if(err) console.log(err);
  else console.log("file saved");
});
```

This is inside a function with a bunch of attributes.
If I do `console.log(this)`, it shows the object but when I save it, the file has only this:

```
[object Object]
```

Since I didn't get the answer I wanted, I want to clarify a bit what I want.
I want my object to be stored as an object but not as a json file or txt file. If I have a mp3 stream for example, I want this stream to be stored as a mp3 file not a json file. Someone knows how to do this?

Comment: check out this question first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976567/write-objects-into-file-with-node-js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Node [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) for FileSystem, the second parameter needs to be a string, buffer or UintArray.
To persist the object to the file, convert the object to a string using `JSON.stringify(obj)` and call the `fs.writeFile()` API.

Here is the code snippet for the same:

```
fs.writeFile("file.bin", JSON.stringify(obj), 'binary', (err)=>{
   if(err) console.log(err)
   else console.log('File saved')
})
```

Another way is to use a buffer in place of the string.

```
var buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(obj))
fs.writeFile("file.bin", buffer, 'binary', (err)=>{
   if(err) console.log(err)
   else console.log('File saved')
})
```

Comment: Is the data stored as a string or as an object as a result of this? Also, what is the quickest? The string or the buffer?

Answer (score 0):

You can't save it as an object to a file, but you can save it as a textual representation of an object. You need to turn the object into a string using `JSON.stringify`. Like this:

```
var myObj = {a:123,b:456};
JSON.stringify(myObj);
```

or in your case:

```
JSON.stringify(this);
```

Then when you need to access it, you can turn it back into an object with `JSON.parse()`

**References**

[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

[`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: I don't want to save it as a text file but as an object. I want it to use the least space possible.

Comment: You can't save it as an object to a file, but you can save it as a textual representation of an object. Then when you need to access it, you can turn it back into an object with `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can save an object to a file, what do you think pictures are?

Consider something like:

```
  const fd = fs.openSync('myFile.bin', 'w')
  fs.writeSync(fd, Buffer.from(myObject, 'base64'))
```