# How to write an array into a file in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, tostring, fs

I have an array of object like this

I want to write this code into a file such that I can dump into my db.

```
data =  [{"test":"1"},{"test":"2"}]
function writeFinalData (data) {
  var toWriteListXml = config.exportPath + 'data.json',
  toWriteData = data.toString();
  fs.writeFile(toWriteListXml, toWriteData, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("The file was saved!");
  });
}
```

With this code ,I can see in my file as

```
[Object Object],[Object Object]
```

Can anyone please help me to write my data as it is like an array.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify(data);` instead of `data.toString();`.

Comment: @Shubham why don't you post an answer?

Comment: Especially this answer: [Write objects into file with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31350277/3993662)