# Is it possible to output entire scope in template Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Any node in the scope can be outputted like this:

```
{{variable}}
```

could you output the entire scope somehow? something like

```
{{$scope}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a proof of concept, I created a *directive* to pretty-print the current scope.

You may use it anywhere, simply by adding `<scope />` into the template.

Please note that this is just an idea and has several issues:

1. It depends on `ngSanitize` to make `ng-bind-html` work.
2. It executes `prettyScope()` several times within an `$apply()` so it may become sluggish when `$scope` objects are large and/or have many chained updates (I guess).

The out-of-this-world implementation of `syntaxHighlight` is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7220510/2942409).

Full code and some scope inheritance and isolate scope cases on [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/49FG22NmPD5i8OJLq2lO?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

```
$scope.scope = $scope

{{scope}}
```

Yet, just out of curiosity, why would you do that?

**Edit**

I didn't test this before answering. Mea culpa. This seems not to work, i get a string of "$SCOPE".

However, as mentioned in the comments, shouldn't `console.dir()` do the job?

Comment: my data-binding in ie-8 isn't working for some fields, so I'm trying to figure out where the data is.

Comment: Why not `console.dir()`?

Comment: IE 8 doesn't have `console.dir`.

Comment: please let me know if you have a better option for this!

Comment: I had the same experience, outputting $scope

Comment: AngularJS will not stringify scopes, see [the source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L945). You could write your own filter, call it `debug`, that calls `JSON.stringify` directly rather than through `angular.toJson`.

Answer (score -1):

Of course it is! Check out this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JBTMSBb9e52G61YCz4mF?p=preview).

Since $scope references itself, you need to use an altered stringify method. Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json) for that!

But another great option for exploring the scope is [Batarang](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang). Check it out! Unfortunately it's only for chrome.

Comment: Yep! Check my edited post for a plunkr of how to display the $scope.

Comment: If you're a Firefox user, checkout a small Firebug extension called [AngScope](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/angscope-simple-angularjs-s/) I've written. It helps you inspect `$scope` objects into Firebug's DOM inspector.