# SAPUI5 copy model and break binding?

Tags: json, sapui5

On initialization I read an oData service to get a small list of values and I store the model for further use in the application.

```
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oODataJSONModel, "xlist");
```

At multiple stages, I want to make a copy of the original model, make changes to the values list and use it in a Select drop down. I've tried multiple different things, but every time I update/delete the copied model values, it is instantly reflected in the original model. This seems like a simple ask, but is there a way to break the link between the original model and the copied model, ideally I want to keep the original list intact so that list can be re-used over and over, regardless of what changes are made to the copies?

```
            var oModelCpy = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

            var cpyModelArray = oOrigModel.getData();

            cpyModelJsonData = { results : [ cpyModelArray ] };

            oModelCpy.setData(cpyModelJsonData );
```

When I remove entries from the copy model, it also removes entries from the original model, which in this case is not what i want.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I'm facing the same issue, tried deep copying the js object using jquery.extend and JSON.parse, but the changes on one model still affects the other.

Answer (score 6):

A better approach is to save your data in the success handler:

```
oODataJSONModel.read("/yourService",  
  null,  
  null,  
  false,  
  function(oData, oResponse){  
    var oODataJSONModel =  new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();  
    oODataJSONModel.setData(oData);  
    this.getView().setModel(oODataJSONModel, "jsonModel");
  }
);
```

---

**EDIT**

I just stumbled upon this question while I was browsing through the list of UI5 questions, and it dawned to me what is causing your underlying copy issue! :-)

*If you copy an array **of objects** to a new array (which is also happens if you copy model data to another model), **you won't get a new array with new objects***

Instead, you actually will get a new array, but with **references** to the old objects. So any change you make to a value in an object inside an array in model 1, will end up having that same value in model 2

So, in effect, you need to create new objects based on the old ones. Luckily, you don't need costly `for` loops and hardcoded value-copying logic to achieve this; one single line should be ok.

Let's say your original data is referenced by an array `aData`.
You then copy this data (a true copy) to a new array using JSON:

```
var aDataCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(aData));
```

If you now set this `aDataCopy` as the data for your second model, it will not have any references to the old model anymore.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Qualiture (congrats on HDE recognition also btw), so this is exactly the steps i have done in the initialization part, i only wanted to call the service once, but I use the model in multiple sections within the application. I thought this would be a simple task, but i want to keep the original model/data values intact, and be able to make copies of the model that i can update/delete entries for as required, but keep those updates/deletes local to the copied model.

Comment: You're welcome! And humbly thrilled to be part of it indeed! ;-)

Comment: Well deserved for sure, sorry I hit enter on the first comment and I edited it now to add the additional info i wanted to add.

Comment: So, any updates you do on the local model are instantly reflected to the ODataModel too? That's weird indeed... Maybe the oData metadata is wrecking havoc, and just use `oData.results` (i.e. the array containing the plain results) instead?

Comment: Yeah, i thought by just taking the data (getData) from the original model, using the code above, adding it to oModelCpy that I would be safe to splice values in the copied model without altering the original model. Somehow it keeps the binding back to the original model and removes the same entries. I can't understand how it's keeping that link intact, when in my mind I've only taken the data and not the property or reference of the original model. I tried you're suggestion, with the cpyModelArray = oOrigModel.oData.results, again, same outcome.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm pretty sure I've used this approach on a former project, and did not experience any issues with it... will have to dig up some old code to see how I did it exactly

Comment: Thanks Qualiture, not sure what i actually did to hack around it, but tried this out in a simple test and it worked fine. Marking it so more folks might find it useful. Thanks again.

Comment: @Qualiture I get a converting circular structure to json error, when I use the solution. The first time it works fine. I have a dialog box in which if I make a change and press cancel, I want to show old values on reopening it. But currently it shows changed values.

Comment: @THI You need to clean up your circular references first. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json/11616993. Generally speaking, circular references are a coding/structure error and should never happen in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery extend() method to make a copy of the data. I had similar troubles earlier.

`var newObject = $.extend({},oldObject);`

Try this for once. Find the reference at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/