# Save an string representation of an unknown JS object in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets

I'm saving a connection/socket object in my program as follows:

```
var clients = [];
net.createServer(function (socket) {
    clients.push(socket);
    //morecode...
```

Later on the code I use that array to broadcast a message:

```
function broadcast(message, sender) {
    clients.forEach(function (client) {
        client.write(message);
    });
}
```

So far very simple. Now, I want to save the socket variable in my mongodb server so I can access it from different instances of my server application. My first approach was to do something like:

```
var client = new Client({
    name: socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort,
    socket: JSON.stringify(socket)
});

client.save(function (err) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
});
```

But I got: **TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON**
A suggestion I got from a similar question here in SO is to use [util.inspect](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options), with that I can manage to save an string representation of the socket var:

**console.log(socket)**

```
Socket {
  _connecting: false,
  _hadError: false,
  _handle:
   TCP {
     _externalStream: {},
     fd: 14,
     reading: true,
     owner: [Circular],
     onread: [Function: onread],
     onconnection: null,
     writeQueueSize: 0 },
  _parent: null,
  _host: null,
  _readableState:
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: [],
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: true,
     sync: false,
     needReadable: true,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events:
   { end: { [Function: g] listener: [Function: onend] },
     finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
     _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd] },
  _eventsCount: 3,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _writableState:
   WritableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     needDrain: false,
     ending: false,
     ended: false,
     finished: false,
     decodeStrings: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     length: 0,
     writing: false,
     corked: 0,
     sync: true,
     bufferProcessing: false,
     onwrite: [Function],
     writecb: null,
     writelen: 0,
     bufferedRequest: null,
     lastBufferedRequest: null,
     pendingcb: 0,
     prefinished: false,
     errorEmitted: false },
  writable: true,
  allowHalfOpen: false,
  destroyed: false,
  bytesRead: 0,
  _bytesDispatched: 0,
  _sockname: null,
  _pendingData: null,
  _pendingEncoding: '',
  server:
   Server {
     domain: null,
     _events: { connection: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _connections: 1,
     _handle:
      TCP {
        _externalStream: {},
        fd: 12,
        reading: false,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: null,
        onconnection: [Function: onconnection],
        writeQueueSize: 0 },
     _usingSlaves: false,
     _slaves: [],
     _unref: false,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     pauseOnConnect: false,
     _connectionKey: '6::::5000' } }
```

**console.log(util.inspect(socket))**

> { socket: 'Socket {\n  _connecting:
>   false,\n  _hadError: false,\n  _handle: \n   TCP {\n
>   _externalStream: {},\n     fd: 14,\n     reading: true,\n     owner: [Circular],\n     onread: [Function: onread],\n     onconnection:
>   null,\n     writeQueueSize: 0 },\n  _parent: null,\n  _host: null,\n 
>   _readableState: \n   ReadableState {\n     objectMode: false,\n     highWaterMark: 16384,\n     buffer: [],\n     length: 0,\n     pipes:
>   null,\n     pipesCount: 0,\n     flowing: null,\n     ended: false,\n 
>   endEmitted: false,\n     reading: true,\n     sync: false,\n
>   needReadable: true,\n     emittedReadable: false,\n
>   readableListening: false,\n     resumeScheduled: false,\n
>   defaultEncoding: \'utf8\',\n     ranOut: false,\n     awaitDrain: 0,\n
>   readingMore: false,\n     decoder: null,\n     encoding: null },\n 
>   readable: true,\n  domain: null,\n  _events: \n   { end: { [Function:
>   g] listener: [Function: onend] },\n     finish: [Function:
>   onSocketFinish],\n     _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd] },\n 
>   _eventsCount: 3,\n  _maxListeners: undefined,\n  _writableState: \n   WritableState {\n     objectMode: false,\n     highWaterMark: 16384,\n
>   needDrain: false,\n     ending: false,\n     ended: false,\n
>   finished: false,\n     decodeStrings: false,\n     defaultEncoding:
>   \'utf8\',\n     length: 0,\n     writing: false,\n     corked: 0,\n
>   sync: true,\n     bufferProcessing: false,\n     onwrite:
>   [Function],\n     writecb: null,\n     writelen: 0,\n
>   bufferedRequest: null,\n     lastBufferedRequest: null,\n
>   pendingcb: 0,\n     prefinished: false,\n     errorEmitted: false },\n
>   writable: true,\n  allowHalfOpen: false,\n  destroyed: false,\n 
>   bytesRead: 0,\n  _bytesDispatched: 0,\n  _sockname: null,\n 
>   _pendingData: null,\n  _pendingEncoding: \'\',\n  server: \n   Server {\n     domain: null,\n     _events: { connection: [Function] },\n
>   _eventsCount: 1,\n     _maxListeners: undefined,\n     _connections: 1,\n     _handle: \n      TCP {\n        _externalStream: {},\n
>   fd: 12,\n        reading: false,\n        owner: [Circular],\n
>   onread: null,\n        onconnection: [Function: onconnection],\n
>   writeQueueSize: 0 },\n     _usingSlaves: false,\n     _slaves: [],\n
>   _unref: false,\n     allowHalfOpen: false,\n     pauseOnConnect: false,\n     _connectionKey: \'6::::5000\' },\n  _peername: { address:
>   \'::ffff:XXXXXXX\', family: \'IPv6\', port: 1145 },\n' }' }

In that form, I can save it to mongodb, but I have no idea **how to reconvert it to a socket object nodejs can use**.

Comment: I doubt it is possible. `net.Socket` uses TCP sockets, and you basically want 2 different processes use the same socket simultaneously.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Another work around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11616993/3011380) to solve `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`, to custom `JSON.stringify` as below

```
var cache = [];
var obj = JSON.stringify(sock, function(key, value) {
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
        if (cache.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
            // Circular reference found, discard key
            return;
        }
        // Store value in our collection
        cache.push(value);
    }
    return value;
});
cache = null; // Enable garbage collection

console.log(obj);
```

So it is easy to reconvert it to a socket object through `JSON.parse`

```
console.log(JSON.parse(obj));
```

Comment: this does not work as the object you get back after parsing such an object is not a socket object anymore.