# Converting file into JSON using JWPlayer

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-web-services, jwplayer

Hey guys so I have this problem placing in captions into my video.

I'm placing my .vtt as a value inside my object but it seems like the browser doesn't like the way it was output. I'm following this guide [here](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1407438-adding-closed-captions)

This is the Error that pops up on my console

```
    {name: "", message: "Converting circular structure to JSON", error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON at Object.stringify (native) at Object.<ano…}
```

**captions-en.vtt**

```
00:00:01.000 --> 00:00:15.000
What brings you to the land
of the gatekeepers?

00:00:15.500 --> 00:00:20.500
I'm searching for someone.

00:00:36.500 --> 00:00:39.000
A dangerous quest for a lone hunter.

00:00:41.500 --> 00:00:44.000
I've been alone for as long
as I can remember.
```

**Javascript**

```
jwplayer("my-video").setup({
    file: "<my-video-file>",
    width: "100%",
    aspectratio: "24:10",
    primary: "flash",
    tracks: [{
        file: "/assets/captions/captions-en.vtt",
        label: "English",
        kind: "captions"
    }]
});
```

I also made sure I saved as "UTF-8" encoding.

Is there another step I'm missing. Like a parse method?

Also note that I'm streaming the video from **AWS S3 Bucket**. Would that be the reason causing the error that I would have to upload the vtt file on there?

The error is the same in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json) but they showed how they did it by placing in a string. How would I go about it if it came from a vtt file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON.stringify, avoid TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)

Comment: You already checked the VTT with something like this? https://quuz.org/webvtt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also note that I'm streaming the video from AWS S3 Bucket. Would that be the reason causing the error that ***I would have to upload the vtt file on there?***

Yes, upload the VTT file wherever your video happens to be. There are security restrictions on VTTs and in my own experience, I have yet to successfully run JWPlayer using a VTT that's in a different bucket than the video.

Make sure you check the VTT file is valid by running it at https://quuz.org/webvtt/

S3 might treat your VTT generically by defaulting it's `content-type` as `application/octet-stream`. I'm not sure how you are using S3, but if you can check the VTT's properties **after** it's uploaded, look for this property:

```
Content-Type: binary/octet-stream
```

If you see that, then you need to change it to this:

```
Content-Type: text/vtt
```

If you don't have an established process and/or tools to check the VTT on S3, use the freeware version of S3 Browser or Cloudberry S3 Explorer.

About that error:

`{name: "", message: "Converting circular structure to JSON", error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON at Object.stringify (native) at Object.<ano…}`

I don't think it's the VTT file is what that error's about. If you look at it's formatting, VTT has no similarities to a JSON whatsoever, but the structure of a JW setup syntax is very similar.