# JSON.stringify: JSON string will be empty

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

```
var clients = [];

var tmp = [];

tmp["username"] = rows[0].username;
tmp["rank"] = rows[0].rank;
tmp["lastaction"] = "0";
tmp["connection"] = connection;
clients.push(tmp);

JSON.stringify(clients)
```

I initialized an array (clients) and pushed an associative array (tmp) to the clients array.
But if I "stringify" the client, it will just return "[[]]".

What did I wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try like below.
var tmp = {};

there is no concept of associative array in js. it is json object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should turn `tmp` to an object literal rather than an array literal.

```js
var clients = [];

var tmp = {};

tmp["username"] = "foo";
tmp["rank"] = 1;
tmp["lastaction"] = "0";
tmp["connection"] = "bar";
clients.push(tmp);

console.log(JSON.stringify(clients))
```

Answer (score 3):

update your code like this

```
var tmp = {};
```

Asssociative array has not support directly in javascript you can make as object

Comment: Thank you, but this throws an error when sending it to the node.js client:
    connection.sendUTF(JSON.stringify({response: "loginsucceed", onlinelist: JSON.stringify(clients)}));

"TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"

Comment: please follow this link might be it will helps you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `tmp` as an object:

```js
var clients = [];

var tmp = {};

tmp["username"] = 'username';
tmp["rank"] = 1
tmp["lastaction"] = 2
tmp["connection"] = 3
clients.push(tmp);

console.log(JSON.stringify(clients));
```