# axios gives me converting circular structure to json error while sending the data

Tags: node.js, axios

My code is as shown below:

```
axios.post('https://api.sandbox.xyz.com/v1/order/new', JSON.stringify({
            "request": "/v1/order/new",
            "nonce": 123462,

            "client_order_id": "20150102-4738721",
            "symbol": "btcusd",
            "amount": "1.01",
            "price": "11.13",
            "side": "buy",
            "type": "exchange limit"
        }), config)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            res.json({
                data: JSON.stringify(response)
            })
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.send({
                status: '500',
                message: error
            })
        });
```

Now it is saying that `Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`  for the code `res.json({data:JSON.stringify(response)})`

So, is there anything missing in this code ?

Comment: Maybe you mean `JSON.stringify(response.data)`? The `response` itself presumably contains circular references (probably in `response.request`).

Comment: yes even if I write `res.json({data:response})` ,  the error remains same

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: Yes , I put ` console.log("response is " + response.request)`, but it is saying `response is [object object]`

Comment: What I suggested is `res.json({ data: JSON.stringify(response.data) });`

Comment: This is the solution for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11616993/7445344 I know its not the prettiest

Comment: @LakiGeri That's only necessary if you're truly trying to serialize something with circular references. Here, it's almost certainly just a mistake that the thing being serialized has a circular reference. (This code is trying to serialize a `response` object when that's very likely not the intention.)

Answer (score 37):

```
axios.post('https://api.sandbox.xyz.com/v1/order/new', JSON.stringify({
            "request": "/v1/order/new",
            "nonce": 123462,
            "client_order_id": "20150102-4738721",
            "symbol": "btcusd",
            "amount": "1.01",
            "price": "11.13",
            "side": "buy",
            "type": "exchange limit"
        }), config)
        .then(function(response) {
            res.send(response.data)
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            res.send({
                status: '500',
                message: error
            })
        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Spent a couple hours on a problem and all I needed to change was my response to response.data....

Comment: That's actually a great and simple answer! Kudos!

Answer (score 21):

This happens many a time with `axios` because sometimes we directly return the response from the endpoint. For example, this error will occur if we pass the response directly, rather than passing the `response.data`.

```
response = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
res.send(response); // error
res.send(response.data); // works perfectly
```

Comment: You're rigth, this worked fine for me !

Answer (score 10):

The problem might be because of the response you are sending out to the client is not a JSON object.
In my case, I solved the error by simply sending the JSON part of the response object.

```js
res.status(200).json({
  success:true,
  result:result.data
})
```

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me.

```
res.status(200).json({
   data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data)
}));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
res.json({ data: JSON.stringify(response.data) });
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try to add error handler interceptor:

```
const handle_axios_error = function(err) {

    if (err.response) {
        const custom_error = new Error(err.response.statusText || 'Internal server error');
        custom_error.status = err.response.status || 500;
        custom_error.description = err.response.data ? err.response.data.message : null;
        throw custom_error;
    }
    throw new Error(err);

}

axios.interceptors.response.use(r => r, handle_axios_error);
axios.post(....)
```

Thanks [Sepehr Vakili](https://github.com/sepehrvakili) for his post https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/836#issuecomment-390342342

Comment: This really help me, before this I was dumping the request or response object and it would be huge (certificates, circular structure etc). Now I get exactly what I need to debug