# Any way to write req object of callback route to a file in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, middleware

All I want is to log my req/res object to a file(so i can refer to it later for any object values) on redirecting to a particular page.

I tried this:

```
app.get("/route", function(req, res) {
res.render("route");
fs.writeFile('./data.json', JSON.stringify(req, null, 2) , 'utf-8', function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

The above code is throwing error as so:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON at Object.Stringify (native)
```

Is there anything I should be doing differently? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON.stringify, avoid TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)

Comment: Why do you want to save the entire object? What fields do you want to store?

Comment: Specifically for you case I'd consider this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18354289/1053772

Comment: use `util.inspect` instead of `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Thanks @juandemarco for that link.

Comment: Thank @Almis , using util.inspect works for me as I'm trying to stringify an object which is circular structure and using util.inspect translates that into a [circular] object instead.

Answer (score 0):

`req` contains a reference to the `res` object, and `res` contains a reference back to `req`, so it really is a circular reference where stringify will not work.

A quick solution might be to be more choosy about which properties you want to save. For example, save `req.body` to file - just be picky about the data you really need.

---

Long term, you should consider if this is what you really want. File I/O is "expensive". You might want to put data into a database, or keep it in memory somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Are you need all req-object to save?

If you should save only query, try this:

```
app.get("/route", function(req, res) {
     res.render("route");
     fs.writeFile('./data.json', JSON.stringify(req.query, null, 2), 
    'utf-8', function(err) {
         if(err) {
              return console.log(err);
         }
    console.log("The file was saved!");
 });
```

if you want any additional data, firstly create new object, and assign this data to that object, and use `JSON.stringify(yourObject, null, 2)`