# JSON.stringify can the "null" parm prevent circular structure?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to figure out what the "null" means?

```
JSON.stringify(myJsonObj, null, 2)
```

I see people using "undefined" or "null"

Couldn't figure out what the "null" was for so I just removed it.

```
JSON.stringify(myJsonObj)
```

So now I start getting these

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

Could this be the reason?

What exactly does Null do?

Comment: [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Parameters)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON.stringify, avoid TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)

Comment: @DerekBrown my question goes more on what the "replacer" (null) does?

Comment: Using `null` as the replacer function is the same as not providing the argument at all -- the only reason to do that is so you can provide the `space` argument without a replacer. It shouldn't affect whether you get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.stringify`; can take 3 parameters,
`(value,replacer,space)`

- `value` is the object you want to stringify, in your case `myJsonObj`
- `replacer` A function that alters the behavior of the stringification process.
- `space` object that's used to insert white space into the output JSON string for readability purposes

in your case the `myJsonObj` contains circular structure which needs to be corrected in the replacer function 
maybe you can get help from here:
[JSON.stringify, avoid TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)
to know how you can convert you objects within "myJsonObj".

Comment: @Derek  "A function that alters the behavior of the stringification process" - how is it altered?  Does it skip fields with null value or?   There is very little info about this online.

Comment: @torbenrudgaard I did not write this answer- am just the editor. There is a lot about this online.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter