# Outputting value from input field in javascript

Tags: javascript, protractor

i have a input field where I send an input value:

```
var firstNumber = element(by.model('first'));    
firstNumber.sendKeys(1);
```

I want to write the value of input box ('1') on console. When I use following:

```
console.log("Value from input box is: " + firstNumber.getAttribute('value'));
```

I get following answer:

```
Value from input box is: [object Object]
```

How can I get the actual value.

p.s. This may seem very silly question, but I'm absolutely new to javascript, which I'm using in protractor End to end testing using Jasmine framework.

Comment: console.log(JSON.Stringify(firstNumber.getAttribute('value')))

Comment: Assuming `firstNumber` is a textbox, then `firstNumber.value` ought to work

Comment: @ADyson Using firstNumber.value gives "Value from input box is: undefined"

Comment: @KalleshwarKalshetty Using your method gives following error:

 Message:
    Failed: JSON.Stringify is not a function

Comment: @KalleshwarKalshetty should be `JSON.stringify` (lower case s)

Comment: @KalleshwarKalshetty Now it fails with...

 Message:
    Failed: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: please take a look @ here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json/11616993

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`firstNumber.getAttribute('value')` does not return an actual attribute value but rather **it returns a promise**, which has  `[object Object]` string representation ([documentation reference](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md#promises-and-the-control-flow)).

You need to resolve the promise to access the actual value:

```
firstNumber.getAttribute('value').then(function (value) {
    console.log("Value from input box is: " + value);
});
```