# Proper way to get XPath lists in Chrome Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, promise, puppeteer

I'm using Chrome Puppeteer to get at some content on a Web page. This content is a list of items in a pseudo-table. I'm using XPath to get this content.

When I tested the Xpath expression [in Chrome with the the XPath Helper Extension] it displays the list of text, so I know the XPath expression is fine.

However, I'm having issues trying to do this with Puppeteer. Below is the relevant code [I omitted the opening and closing puppeteer code]:

```
var xpath_expr_str = "//div[contains(@class,'listings')]/div[4]/p/a";
var page_url_str = 'https://my-url';

await page.goto(page_url_str);
await page.waitForXPath(xpath_expr_str);

var xpath_payload_arr = await page.$x(xpath_expr_str);
var xpath_val_arr = await page.evaluate(function(payload_arr){
    var url_list_arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < payload_arr.length; i++)
    {
        url_list_arr.push(payload_arr[i].textContent);
    }
    return url_list_arr;
}, xpath_payload_arr);

console.log(xpath_val_arr);
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

I can't seem to get at the list. But, the thing is if I try to just get at a single item in the list, it works ok. For example, the following code works:

```
var xpath_val_str = await page.evaluate(function(payload_arr){
    return payload_arr.textContent;
}, xpath_payload_arr[0]);
console.log(xpath_val_str);
```

What's the proper way to manage XPath lists when working with Puppeteer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot pass `xpath_payload_arr` into `page.evaluate` because it's a complex object that obviously contains somewhere a reference to itself. [More on "Converting circular structure to JSON" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json/11616993)

However we can iterate over it in node context and `page.evaluate` items one by one:

```
var xpath_expr_str = '//*[@id="questions"]/div/div/h3/a';
var page_url_str = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/puppeteer';

await page.goto(page_url_str);
await page.waitForXPath(xpath_expr_str);

var xpath_payload_arr = await page.$x(xpath_expr_str);

var url_list_arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < xpath_payload_arr.length; i++)
{
    url_list_arr.push(await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, xpath_payload_arr[i]));
}

console.log(url_list_arr);
```

This produces the expected result:

[image: xpath evaluation result]

Comment: Super!! Thx a lot, nice advice!