# How can I turn the Google Maps API Map object into a JSON string for storage in local storage?

Tags: javascript, json

I am working with the google maps API and I am trying to convert the map object into a JSON string to store it in local storage. For some reason when I run this block of code the second console.log never runs and when I look in local storage it still says [object Object] meaning the JSON.strigify() never worked.

```
map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: this.state.center,
    zoom: 8.5
});
console.log(map);
let jsonMap = JSON.stringify(map);
console.log(jsonMap);
```

I could be missing something very obvious but I just can't see it.

Cheers,

Comment: I'm not familiar with the google maps API;  What does `map` actually return?  Are you 100% sure it is a JSON object?  Could it be something else (Possibly an array?).  Try running `console.log("type of map: ", typeof map);` and see that that returns.

Comment: Interesting I did that and nothing was console logged. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: What happens if you wrap it in a Try/Catch? Could there be a circular reference in map?

Comment: I wrapped it in a try catch and there is still no response which is even weirder. I am going to run through the debugger a number more times.

Answer (score 2):

You will get a type error trying to stringify the map. It is pretty complex in structure and content.

Why are you trying to save it to a local storage anyway? You would be better saving the options that build the map instead of the map object itself i.e. latitude, longitude, zoom etc.

If you really need to go down the stringify route check this post out:

[JSON.stringify, avoid TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json/11616993)

Comment: I am trying to save it in localStorage for use offline. The circular structure is the tricky bit that I need to learn. Thank you for that suggestion.

Comment: ah I see! Out of interest, do you plan on allowing the user drag the map - i.e. how would you load new map tiles if they are offline

Comment: So I don't think that would be possible. I am looking into static maps for offline but I am not sure how the markers would remain.

Comment: Static maps was going to be my suggestion. I think it is possible to pass in marker data in the static map URL request although I haven't done that myself

Comment: Yes you can add it in but I think there isn't an option for interactivity with that marker.

Comment: Hmm yeah that does make sense. It is possible to convert a lat long to a pixel, doing that might help you work out where the markers are displayed on the map image. You could then create clickable elements from that