# Show all object variables in chrome dev tools (vuejs)

Tags: vue.js

I am in debug mode of chrome. I clicked somewheere, went to chrome console and wrote this

```
this.$parent
```

I want to get parent object variables.  but it shows:

```
VueComponent {_uid: 641, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: VueComponent, …}
$attrs: (...)
$children: [VueComponent]
```

It goes like this. I need to see all variables. I need to use a variable from parent so i try to call it. First i need to see where it is.

So, I will need to open all those variables with three dots `(...)`

I can click but there are hundreds of them. SO best way is printing.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I suggest you use the debugger by adding breakpoints rather than to use the console.

Comment: You could simply print the object as a string to the console. `JSON.stringify` won't work, because of circular structures, but you could just add [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48254637/3233827) for debugging. Certainly not the most elegant solution.