# Vuex commit : JSON circular structure error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am using Vue.js with the vuex store. I call an API method to validate an item, the method returns an array of errors and an array of warnings.

My vuex action :

```
export function validateitemReview ({ commit, dispatch, state }, { reviewId, type, itemreviewData }) {
  console.log('*** validateItemReview() called')
  return api.post(`/clients/districts/reviews/${reviewId}/${type}/validate`, itemreviewData).then(response => {
    console.log('response.data :')
    console.log(response.data)
    commit('setItemReviewsErrors', 'teststring')
  })
}
```

As you can see, i'm not doing much with the response yet. The called `setItemReviewsErrors` mutation in the vuex store :

```
export const setItemReviewsErrors = (state, data) => {
  console.log('*** setItemReviewsErrors() called, data:')
  console.log(data)
}
```

Here comes my problem, my console output is the following :

```
*** validateItemReview() called
response.data :
{
    fatal_errors: []
    warnings: []
    __proto__: Object
}
*** setItemReviewsErrors() called, data:
teststring
```

directly followed by this error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at eval (vuex-persistedstate.es.js?0e44:1)
    at eval (vuex-persistedstate.es.js?0e44:1)
    at eval (vuex.esm.js?2f62:392)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Store.commit (vuex.esm.js?2f62:392)
    at Store.boundCommit [as commit] (vuex.esm.js?2f62:335)
    at local.commit (vuex.esm.js?2f62:651)
    at eval (itemreview_actions.js?0d87:62)
```

`itemreview_actions.js?0d87:62` is the following line in my vuex `validateitemReview()` action:

```
commit('setItemReviewsErrors', 'teststring')
```

if I comment it, no more error. I can't figure where could be my "circular structure" when the problems seems to come from committing a simple string.

Even better, why:

- my `console.log()` from the `setItemReviewsErrors` mutation is still printed and the error comes after even though the error seems to be while calling this method
- If I reload the page (Ctrl+R in browser), there are no errors but if I leave it (go to another page) and then come back to it, the error is thrown again.

### Update

The problem seems to come from the plugin `vuex-persistedstate` . I found out that the vuex store of this application is using it. I am not alone with this problem :

- https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate/issues/152
- https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate/issues/41

But the dev just closes the tickets. If anyone has a lead to solve that, I   am not allowed to remove the persistence plugin.

Comment: Use a parser that supports circular json. https://github.com/WebReflection/flatted

Comment: this could be a workaround but there is no reason JSON thinks there is a circular structure here, so i'd like to solve that first

Comment: a [JSON](http://json.org/) is a string. how can it contain a circular reference?

Comment: I'm obviously missing something because indeed, how is this possible ?

Comment: problem seems to be comming from vuex-persistedstate plugin (question updated)

Comment: @Tom I had exactly the same problem using this plugin (https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate/issues/146#issuecomment-442808260) My code work well without this plugin but fail to convert my JSON when it's enabled. 
I just remove it from my dependencies and rework a little my code to have the same behavior. The dev seem to close all the issues about this error but I think their is a problem inside the plugin code.

Comment: @Jérôme I changed the plugin and I have kind of the same problem. Sadly I need a persistence plugin, I cannot just remove it :(

Comment: If you want I can explain to you how I made it to work. But it depend of your needs (and if you have the same need as me) but it not related with this question.

Comment: Thank you, I found another workaround, I don't need to use the store for this specific feature now, but this leaves this question unsolved....

Comment: It's an interesting question. Looking at vuexpersistedstate index.js it just calls JSON.stringify in one place with `return storage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(state))`, so your state must have the circular reference, which may cause other problems even if you remove vuexpersistedstate. Could you post your state?

Comment: This is likely the root problem you need to solve [JSON.stringify, avoid TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json/11616993). It may be more subtle, as Vuex state is dynamic and the circular refernce only occurs after a certain mutation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this alternate library, [vuex-persist](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist#circular-states), they meet this problem head-on

> If you have circular structures in your state

```
let x = { a: 10 }  
x.x = x  
x.x === x.x.x // true  
x.x.x.a === x.x.x.x.a //true
```

> JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify() will not work.
>
> You'll need to install circular-json

```
npm install circular-json
```

> And when constructing the store, add supportCircular flag

```
new VuexPersistence({
  supportCircular: true,
  ...
})
```

However, a circular reference in state may cause you other problems, if at some stage a reactive property triggers another call to the same mutation. That said, you would likely see the problem quickly as a **Maximum call stack size exceeded** error.

See the [comment by Linus Borg](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuex-storing-nested-and-circular-structures/20018/2) on this code

```js
mutations:
saveVideoComment(state, {id, text, videoId}) {
    let comment = {
        id: id,
        videoId: videoId,
        text: text,
        inlineUserVideo: state.userVideos[userVideoId]
    };
    Vue.set(state.videoComments, id, comment);
    state.videos[videoId].comments.push(id);
    state.videos[videoId].inlineComments.push(comment);
}
```

Comment: Even though my boss told me i spent enough time on that and I found another workaround, this seems to be an acceptable answer, thank you !

Comment: LOL You're welcome. Tell your boss you are saving future rework!