# Saving socket connection to JSOn

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using `socket.io` websockets in nodejs. I am trying to stringify the `socket` object to be able to save it into my database. Here is what I am doing:

```
socket.on('open-room', function(arg, callback) {
    var socketStr = JSON.stringify(socket);
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a general solution on how to convert an object into a JSON string without encountering a circular structure error (usually, you would do this for logging or debugging), check out the S.O. answer [Converting Circular Structure to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json). If it's not important exactly what the output format is, you can use the built in `util.inspect(socket)`.

If you're doing this for any reason other than logging, be aware that a socket.io websocket can't be serialized/deserialized (you won't be able to recreate a working websocket using the database record).

You might have better luck crafting a more specific JSON object containing only the keys you actually care about, and storing that in the database, rather than attempting to stringify the entire object.