# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON with app.use(express.json())

Tags: node.js, json, express, slack-api

I have an express web app that has `app.use(express.json())`.  I'm testing the integrations with Slack's [slash commands](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands#app_command_handling), and I had a very basic post function set up:

```
app.post('/info', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('Thanks');
});
```

The issue is whenever my slack app hits `/info`, my app throws

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at stringify (/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1119:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:260:14)
    at app.post (app.js:69:9)
```

Is there a way to fix this error without removing the `app.use(express.json())`?

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json), however I don't believe it pertains as I can't modify express' `express.json()` function.  I've also seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55503044/express-middleware-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json), however it seems like that's due to their use of `res.json` which I am not using.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution to catch the error? I.e. preventing your server from crashing if a circular json is sent?

Comment: @eol Well, I'm wondering why this happens and how to make it not happen.  Currently, I'm unable to ever handle `/info` post request because of it, which is definitely not desirable.

Comment: Are you sending a simple text as the response to the slash command, just like you posted here, or sending JSON?

If you're sending JSON, how are you sending? I am suspecting the JSON structure contains a circular reference.

Alternatively, just use `res.json(obj)` to send a JSON, instead of using the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen your POST payload so I cannot tell for sure. However, it is possible that you are running into this scenario because you from Slack you are POST'ing with the Header `{Content-Type: application/json}` already and inside your Express app you are using the middleware `express.json()` again. If you already know that clients must send the Content-Type: application/json and you expect json object why do you have to use the `express.json()`?

Comment: If you don't understand the question, please add a comment instead of answering it.

Comment: @troy - Thanks for your feedback. Since I am new to SO, I am happy to take your feedback. A couple of things:

1. I am not sure what makes you think I didn't understand the question. Please clarify it. ( I happened to have ran into similar problem, found a solution and wanted to help )
2. If the OP comes back saying what I have suggested solved the problem what happens? 3. It also looks like I need "50 reputation" to comment on the OP's post. 4. Last but not least, do you have a solution/answer to help OP?