# How to log a large object or primitive to the console in NativeScript core on iOS?

Tags: ios, nativescript

Currently, both `console.log` and `console.dir` truncate their output. [Here's a pull request](https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime/pull/1045) that explicitly limited, by default, the size of the console output for the NativeScript *Android* runtime. I couldn't find a similar pull request for the iOS runtime. The pull request for Android added a configuration option that can be set to change the limit but no such option seems to exist for iOS.

Here's a (closed) issue for the main NativeScript project with a comment mentioning that no configuration option seems to be available (or at least known) to change the apparent limit:

- [console.dir not showing full object · Issue #6041 · NativeScript/NativeScript](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/6041)

I checked the NativeScript, NativeScript iOS runtime, and even WebKit sources (on which the NativeScript iOS runtime depends for its JavaScript runtime from what I could tell) and I couldn't find any obvious limit on the size of console messages.

In the interim, I've opted to use this function in my code:

```
function logBigStringToConsole(string) {
  const maxConsoleStringLength = 900; // The actual max length isn't clear.

  const length = string.length;

  if (length < maxConsoleStringLength) {
    console.log(string);
  } else {
    console.log(string.substring(0, maxConsoleStringLength));
    logBigStringToConsole(string.substring(maxConsoleStringLength));
  }
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
logBigStringToConsole(JSON.stringify(bigObject));
```

Comment: You are the best Kenny !! that function helpme to log.

Comment: I hit circular structure error, i wish to direct log an EventData on user tapping it, but JSON cannot stringify a circular structured data

Comment: @elliotching [That's a separate question :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/how-can-i-print-a-circular-structure-in-a-json-like-format) But you might want to combine the interim solution to this one with an answer to the other for your case.