# Unable to convert JavaScript window.screen object into string

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

- I want to convert the `window.screen` attributes and values into a string to send to the back-end. *(I could extract the values for each attribute but curious to understand why the below fails)*
- Not sure why `JSON.stringify(window.screen)` returns `"{}"`.
- Note that the manually created object `orientation_` appears to convert JSON to string fine.

[image: Google Chrome Console-1]

---

- Experimenting further, I tried copying the object and then deleting the `__proto__` object thinking this might be failing the conversion to string. But strangely I am unable to delete any of the keys!

[image: Google Chrome console-2]

---

**Update #1:**

1. Based on below tips that circular reference could be the issue...
   [image: Console-3]
   Here we see that variable `a` has a circular reference to itself. Using [Flatted](https://github.com/WebReflection/flatted#flatted)(circular JSON parser) we see `a` gets converted into String but `window.screen` still doesn't convert.
2. Based on the docs [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), functions are stringified as `null`.So functions are not the problem.

[image: console-6]

*So still not clear on the reason for this behavior.*

Answer (score 1):

The `JSON.stringify` requires object properties to be *stringifiable*. At first sight unfolding `__proto__` part of `window.screen` on console dump one can notice that each of listed attribute is in fact getter function (like `get availHeight: ƒ availHeight()`) and produce result as usual. However `Object.keys(window.screen)` produces empty array that suggests all properties are not enumerable so they cannot be found introspecting object, also by `JSON.stringify`. In contrast your `orientation` object that you stringified has regular properties that by default are enumerable.

Simplest way to stringify `window.screen`, an object with short number of attributes, is to make its copy that call getter each time, and then stringify copy:

```
var scr = {
    width: window.screen.width,
    height: window.screen.height //... }
JSON.stringify(scr); // --> "{"width":1600,"height":900, ...
```

Comment: in fact functions are not the problem, the problem is about internal construction of window object, that in some places refers to itself (so called "circular structures")

Comment: @FlashThunder agreed, OP however did not try to stringify `window` object that has self-references, it was about `window.screen` that does not.

Comment: I guess __proto__ returns screen as well and it's part of the screen object. I had that problem few years ago, found a good solution to stringify even a window object, but, can't find it right now, and don't really remember the solution.

Comment: Yes, it can be done with replacer function for stringify that collects visited references to avoid looping again, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11616993/2151810)

Comment: Thanks @andy. I will certainly be using that as a workaround but still looking to understand the reason for this behavior. I updated my question with an example to show that circular reference is not the cause for this behavior and that functions stringify into null

Comment: This has nothing to do neither with getters, neither with circular references, it's just that these properties are not enumerable: https://jsfiddle.net/1nodye3x/

Comment: @Kaiido you are right, I wrongly used `propertyIsEnumerable` while doing research. Let me reedit my response. Nevertheless there is something more involved, screen has empty prototype chain (does not inherit) yet `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window.screen)` return empty array, while object with non-enumerable properties should have them listed.