# circular structure to JSON in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts

I have this variable on my component's state:

```
chartData: {
            labels:null,
            datasets:null
        }
```

I receive this json from my api to create the chart:

```
{
"labels": [
    "13/7",
    "14/7",
    "15/7"
],
"datasets": [
    {
        "label": "%%%%",
        "data": [
            0,
            18,
            168
        ],
        "backgroundColor": [
            "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)",
            "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)",
            "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

The chart appears with no problem but when I try to print the value of this.state.chartData this appears:

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'HTMLCanvasElement'
    |     property '__reactInternalInstance$khbtn4bp50s' -> object with constructor 'FiberNode'
    --- property 'stateNode' closes the circle

Here is the setState of the variable:

```
this.setState({
        chartData: {

            datasets: response.datasets,
            labels:response.labels
        }
    })
```

the response is the json above.

UPDATED METHOD JUST TO PRINT VALUES:

```
 teste=()=>{

    alert("chart data")

    alert(JSON.stringify(this.state.chartData))

}
```

edit1: print of the console.log(this.state.chartData)

[image]

edit 2: api call:

```
    return fetch(url, {

        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            labels:params.labels,
            datasets:params.datasets
        })

    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            console.log("fetchJsonFromApi " + JSON.stringify(json))
            // making callback optional
            if (callback && typeof callback === "function") {
                callback(json);
            }
            return json;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        });

}
```

Comment: `but when I try to print the value of this.state.chartData` how do you print it?

Comment: I have created a button just to print the variable, updated the question

Comment: Why do you need to print it with `JSON.stringify`? Are you reserializing aggregated data?

Comment: use `console.log(...)` or `console.dir(...)` instead of `alert(JSON.stringify(...))`.

Comment: The problem is that there is not any circular reference.Updated the question with print of the console.log.   I need to seralize because I use that same json as the cody of my request, updated the question with that method too @Thomas

Comment: @carlos I really don't understand what the problem is

Comment: @Thomas the problem is that I am trying to serialize my this.state.chartData variable but i cant because it says that there is a circular reference but there is any circular reference at all

Answer (score 4):

What happens here is that `JSON.stringify` cannot be used for circular data. Circular data is when you have an object that references some other parent object. If `JSON.stringify` printed some circular data, it would be a infinity string.

This probably happen because you are getting some circular data from the response.

If you really want to print it and ignore the circular that, you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/how-can-i-print-a-circular-structure-in-a-json-like-format) that have alot of ways to do so.

What I recommend is using `console.log` instead of `alert` and in the console you will be able to see circular data with no problem.

Here is a demo for showing circular data, wich is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11616993/9119186).

```js
// Demo: Circular reference
var o = {};
o.o = o;

// Note: cache should not be re-used by repeated calls to JSON.stringify.
var cache = [];
JSON.stringify(o, function(key, value) {
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
        if (cache.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
            // Duplicate reference found, discard key
            return;
        }
        // Store value in our collection
        cache.push(value);
    }
    return value;
});
cache = null; // Enable garbage collection

var a = {b:1}
var o = {};
o.one = a;
o.two = a;
// one and two point to the same object, but two is discarded:
console.log(JSON.stringify(o))
```

To remove `_meta` (wich maybe have circular data) you can do:

```
if(Array.isArray(response.datasets){
    let newDataSets = response.datasets.map(({label, data, backgroundColor}) => ({label, data, backgroundColor}))
    // do what you want to do
}
```

Comment: there is no circular data on my variable,thats the problem @Vencovsky

Comment: `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` says the oposite. Inside `response.datasets` you have `_meta`, probably there you have circular data. You say you don't have, but you probably have but you just don't see it. Try removing `_meta` and see what happens.

Comment: and how do I remove the _meta? Because I didnt put that in there my api only retrieves what is in my question

Comment: the meta wasnt the problem, the error is still here @Vencovsky

Comment: @carlos so instead of normal `JSON.stringify`, use the one in the example I showed, it's simple. Why you didn't tried that yet? Please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/how-can-i-print-a-circular-structure-in-a-json-like-format)

Answer (score -2):

If you experience this issue while running your react app locally while using joi-browser npm package. If its work before and it does not work again

I experience the same error when I changed the content of the object variable which I link to my form.

Kindly shutdown the app
then start it again

```
yarn start
npm start
```

Answer (score -2):

this might help someone, I had the same issue and solved it by commenting the code I put after. The issue happened because the function was called twice.

```
before:
    afunctionCall()
    return;
    aFunctionCall()
after:
    afunctionCall()
    // return;
    // aFunctionCall()
```