# I want to fix a "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" error in

Tags: javascript

I want to an "add to cart" feature on a personal project(using Javascript) by saving each food info to localstorage upon clicking but getting this "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" error

I have tried the fast-safe-stringify and circular-json packages but to no avail

```
export const addFood = (food, next) => {
  let cart = [];
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.getItem("cart")) {
      cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    }
    cart.push({
      ...food,
      count: 1
    });
    cart = Array.from(new Set(cart.map(f => f._id))).map(id => {
      return cart.find(f => f._id === id);
    });
    const cartToString = JSON.stringify(cart);
    localStorage.setItem("cart", cartToString);
    next();
  }
};

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'FiberNode'
    |     property 'stateNode' -> object with constructor 'HTMLButtonElement'
    --- property '__reactInternalInstance$v1zqxvbiiip' closes the circle
addFood
src/components/layouts/cartHelpers.js:16
  13 |   cart = Array.from(new Set(cart.map(f => f._id))).map(id => {
  14 |     return cart.find(f => f._id === id);
  15 |   });
> 16 |   const cartToString = JSON.stringify(cart);
     | ^  17 |   localStorage.setItem("cart", cartToString);
  18 |   next();
  19 | }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I print a circular structure in a JSON-like format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/how-can-i-print-a-circular-structure-in-a-json-like-format)

Comment: Can you console log `cart` and/or `food` so we can see the data structure. You should get rid of the circular structure I think.

Comment: [{…}]
0: {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, nativeEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", target: button.btn.btn-outline-warning.mt-2.mb-2, …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)  Cart

Comment: Class {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, nativeEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", target: button.btn.btn-outline-warning.mt-2.mb-2, …} food