# Save data json from web to json file

Tags: javascript

So i have code scraping like this. but this code eror when me save to json file

massage eror = TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    starting at object with constructor 'Node'
         property 'children' -> object with constructor 'Array'
         index 0 -> object with constructor 'Node'
    property 'parent' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify ()

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');
const url = 'https://icons8.com/line-awesome';

axios(url)
 .then(response => {
   const html = response.data;
   const $ = cheerio.load(html)
   const listIcons = $('.icons-group');
   const list = [];

listIcons.each(function () {
  const title = $(this).find('.icons-title').text();
  const icons = [];
  const panjang = $(this).find('.name');
  for (let i = 0; i < panjang.length; i++) {
    icons.push($(panjang[i]).text());
  }
//   console.log(panjang.length);
//   console.log(panjang[0]);
  list.push({
    title,
    icons,
  });
  console.log(list);
 });
  fs.writeFile('nama.json', JSON.stringify(listIcons, null, 4));
})
.catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I print a circular structure in a JSON-like format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/how-can-i-print-a-circular-structure-in-a-json-like-format)

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/how-can-i-print-a-circular-structure-in-a-json-like-format. It suggests ways to avoid circular structures in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Each HTML node is refering somewhere each other html node. just like A node refers its parent then A's parent refers parent of parent. This makes it circular, so this is the reason of your. Just use your need fields like `title` `innerText` instead take all node object.