# Store cirular object in localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to store below object into my localstorage and want to use throughout application. For that I used circular function. But when I recreate object from string then it is not same object. Below is my object.

```
e.exports {client: I}

client: I


browserDetails: {browser: "chrome", version: 80}

permOnClick: true

ringToneFlag: true

ringToneBackFlag: true

connectToneFlag: true

isLoggedIn: true

reconnectInterval: null

reconnectTryCount: 0

localStorage: Storage


length: 13

AsteriskIntegration:ServerIP: ""

auto_saved_sql: "INSERT INTO document_revisions (id,change_log,document_id,doc_id,doc_type,doc_url,date_entered,created_by,filename,file_ext,file_mime_type,revision,deleted,date_modified) VALUES ('e0a40e04-ceb6-dd54-a05d-5e5cc8f4461b','Document Created','390d0e08-1ba9-dcff-1eb8-5e5cc8b83741','','Sugar','','2020-03-02 08:47:40','1','Test.pdf','pdf','application/pdf','1',0,'2020-03-02 08:47:40')"

plivoBrowserSdkJSON: "{"client":{"browserDetails":{"browser":"chrome","version":80},"permOnClick":true,"ringToneFlag":true,"ringToneBackFlag":true,"connectToneFlag":true,"isLoggedIn":true,"reconnectInterval":null,"reconnectTryCount":0,"localStorage":{"AsteriskIntegration:ServerIP":"","endpointID":"001f922acfecfd9498ea0b2b84703ce8f14d2fa55dc96b857bfbfd1ffe9af40d","AsteriskIntegration:Extension":"","AsteriskIntegration:Context":"","AsteriskIntegration:ToggleStatus":"Minimized","AsteriskIntegration:ShowNotification":"0","favorite_tables":"undefined","debug":"","csio_auth_data":"\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.FsF6rn82ss9JcAC9UxqUFeCiTe0xl9WDNNeQHBoFc4s\"","AsteriskIntegration:UserID":"1","AsteriskIntegration:SocketPort":""},"_events":{},"_eventsCount":0,"phone":{"_events":{},"_eventsCount":7,"_cache":{"credentials":{}},"_configuration":{"authorization_user":"david","password":null,"realm":"phone.plivo.com","ha1":"2291bb7891ceefc3ab2221cb1565fba6","display_name":null,"uri":{"_parameters":{},"_headers":{},"_scheme":"sip","_user":"david5719898358329549231","_host":"phone.plivo.com"},"contact_uri":{"_parameters":{"transport":"ws"},"_headers":{},"_scheme":"sip","_user":"r594n4dv","_host":"aeqf7b88emss.invalid","_port":null},"instance_id":"78fdf100-2c4d-4deb-a8ac-0cee371db730","use_preloaded_route":false,"session_timers":false,"session_timers_refresh_method":"UPDATE","no_answer_timeout":60000,"register":true,"register_expires":120,"registrar_server":{"_parameters":{},"_headers":{},"_scheme":"sip","_user":null,"_host":"phone.plivo.com"},"connection_recovery_max_interval":20,"connection_recovery_min_interval":2,"via_host":"aeqf7b88emss.invalid","user_agent":"plivo-browser-sdk 2.1.20","plivosip_id":"out4c","hostport_params":"phone.plivo.com"},"_dynConfiguration":{"register":true},"_dialogs":{},"_applicants":{},"_sessions":{},"_transport":{"status":0,"socket":{"_url":"wss://phone.plivo.com:5063","_sip_uri":"sip:phone.plivo.com:5063;transport=ws","_via_transport":"WSS","_ws":{}},"sockets":[{"weight":0,"status":0}],"recovery_options":{"max_interval":20,"min_interval":2},"recover_attempts":0,"recovery_timer":null,"close_requested":false},"_contact":{"pub_gruu":null,"temp_gruu":null},"_status":1,"_error":null,"_transactions":{"nist":{},"nict":{},"ist":{},"ict":{}},"_data":{},"_closeTimer":null,"_registrator":{"_expires":120,"_call_id":"vsa32oc37nnu7143rk274o","_cseq":2,"_registrationTimer":131,"_registering":false,"_registered":true,"_contact":"<sip:r594n4dv@aeqf7b88emss.invalid;transport=ws>;+sip.ice;reg-id=1;+sip.instance=\"<urn:uuid:78fdf100-2c4d-4deb-a8ac-0cee371db730>\"","_extraHeaders":[],"_extraContactParams":""}},"_currentSession":null,"callSession":null,"callUUID":null,"callDirection":null,"lastCallUUID":null,"_lastCallSession":null,"incomingInvites":{},"incomingCallsInitiationTime":{},"lastIncomingCall":null,"callStats":{},"sipAuthBy":null,"userName":"david5719898358329549231","options":{"codecs":["OPUS","PCMU"],"enableTracking":true,"debug":"DEBUG","permOnClick":true,"enableIPV6":false,"audioConstraints":{},"dscp":true,"appId":"380077084","appSecret":null,"registrationDomainSocket":null,"clientRegion":null,"preDetectOwa":false,"disableRtpTimeOut":false,"allowMultipleIncomingCalls":false},"callstatskey":null,"rtp_enabled":null,"statsioused":false,"audio":{"ringtoneDevices":{},"microphoneDevices":{},"speakerDevices":{}},"owaLastDetect":{"time":0,"isOneWay":true},"owaDetectTime":3600000,"outBoundConnectionStages":[],"_outboundExtraHeaders":{},"_outboundCallNumber":null,"statsSocket":null,"bucketApiUrl":"https://stats.plivo.com/v1/browser/bucketurl/","bucketApiBody":{"username":"david5719898358329549231","password":"lokesh","domain":"phone.plivo.com"},"remoteView":{"width":0,"height":0},"ringToneView":{},"ringBackToneView":{},"connectToneView":{},"audioDevDic":["{\"deviceId\":\"default\",\"kind\":\"audioinput\",\"label\":\"Default\",\"groupId\":\"4ce38a6beefca1618312cc984683f32afdd8a031f04697ce4606940d6456d61b\"}","{\"deviceId\":\"d07a50eedfb049ab16b39ddbb545865947600d3673194a608af977f9ce1cf21f\",\"kind\":\"audioinput\",\"label\":\"Built-in Audio Analog Stereo\",\"groupId\":\"e8c51c00b437c50e95499ec3af71c3ad64bd7f204ee5dc3723471a9e0b8a5291\"}","{\"deviceId\":\"default\",\"kind\":\"audiooutput\",\"label\":\"Default\",\"groupId\":\"default\"}","{\"deviceId\":\"aef20cba2448b4d804e2e968682a01c4b1940595ca9b65de3acc0e16ea987338\",\"kind\":\"audiooutput\",\"label\":\"Built-in Audio Analog Stereo\",\"groupId\":\"e8c51c00b437c50e95499ec3af71c3ad64bd7f204ee5dc3723471a9e0b8a5291\"}"]}}"

endpointID: "001f922acfecfd9498ea0b2b84703ce8f14d2fa55dc96b857bfbfd1ffe9af40d"

AsteriskIntegration:Extension: ""

AsteriskIntegration:Context: ""

AsteriskIntegration:ToggleStatus: "Minimized"

AsteriskIntegration:ShowNotification: "0"

favorite_tables: "undefined"

debug: ""

csio_auth_data: ""eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.41caOjpo4BbY7qknU9HV-R7HIKhb_4ZiybW6njYcnqQ""

AsteriskIntegration:UserID: "1"

AsteriskIntegration:SocketPort: ""

__proto__: Storage


_events: {}

_eventsCount: 0

_maxListeners: undefined

phone: e.exports {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 7, _maxListeners: undefined, _cache: {…}, _configuration: {…}, …}

_currentSession: null

callSession: null

callUUID: null

callDirection: null

lastCallUUID: null

_lastCallSession: null

incomingInvites: Map(0) {}

incomingCallsInitiationTime: Map(0) {}

lastIncomingCall: null

callStats: a {}

sipAuthBy: null

userName: "david5719898358329549231"

options: {codecs: Array(2), enableTracking: true, debug: "DEBUG", permOnClick: true, enableIPV6: false, …}

callstatskey: "73aec46c-4893-41ff-aab9-aa23ef9df7f0"

rtp_enabled: true

statsioused: false

audio: {ringtoneDevices: {…}, microphoneDevices: {…}, speakerDevices: {…}, availableDevices: ƒ, revealAudioDevices: ƒ}

audioConstraints: {}

owaLastDetect: {time: 0, isOneWay: true}

owaDetectTime: 3600000

outBoundConnectionStages: []

_outboundExtraHeaders: {}

_outboundCallNumber: null

statsSocket: s {url: "wss://insights.plivo.com/ws", ws: WebSocket, userName: "david5719898358329549231", callstatskey: "73aec46c-4893-41ff-aab9-aa23ef9df7f0"}

statsCallback: ƒ ()

calcConnStage: ƒ (e)

str: ƒ (e)

bucketApiUrl: URL {href: "https://stats.plivo.com/v1/browser/bucketurl/", origin: "https://stats.plivo.com", protocol: "https:", username: "", password: "", …}

bucketApiBody: {username: "david", password: "abc", domain: "phone.plivo.com"}

remoteView: audio#plivo_webrtc_remoteview

ringToneView: audio#plivo_ringtone

ringBackToneView: audio#plivo_ringbacktone

connectToneView: audio#plivo_connect_tone

audioDevDic: (4) ["{"deviceId":"default","kind":"audioinput","label":…2c403010b9047aa8545d46eda66540c5d9fcd4cec87eb17"}", "{"deviceId":"d07a50eedfb049ab16b39ddbb545865947600…9ef43f5d3efef4e5adabc15779e3ce654fd2ff0ae4c72e7"}", "{"deviceId":"default","kind":"audiooutput","label":"Default","groupId":"default"}", "{"deviceId":"aef20cba2448b4d804e2e968682a01c4b1940…9ef43f5d3efef4e5adabc15779e3ce654fd2ff0ae4c72e7"}"]

plivoSocket: e.exports {_url: "wss://phone.plivo.com:5063", _sip_uri: "sip:phone.plivo.com:5063;transport=ws", _via_transport: "WSS", _ws: WebSocket, onconnect: ƒ, …}

heartbeatTimer: 85

__proto__: o


__proto__: Object
```

And below is my code to convert object to string.

```
const getCircularReplacer = () => {
          const seen = new WeakSet();
          return (key, value) => {
            if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
              if (seen.has(value)) {
                return;
              }
              seen.add(value);
            }
            return value;
          };
        };

        var plivoBrowserSdkJSON = JSON.stringify(plivoBrowserSdk, getCircularReplacer());
```

I followed below answer.

[How can I print a circular structure in a JSON-like format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/how-can-i-print-a-circular-structure-in-a-json-like-format)

Comment: why not just create a class with constroctor to reintialize with the data only.

Answer (score 0):

**// create a class with constructor to reinitialise with the data only**
You cant serialise function. Coz it is not enumeration properties

```
class SomeUtil {

    constructor({ statsSocket, remoteView, ringToneView, ...rest }) {
        this.statsSocket = statsSocket
        this.remoteView = remoteView
        this.ringToneView = ringToneView // some customization
        Object.entries(rest).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            this[key] = value
        })
    }
    statsCallback() {
        console.log(1)
    }
}
const getCircularReplacer = () => {
    const seen = new WeakSet();
    return (key, value) => {
        if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
            if (seen.has(value)) {
                return;
            }
            seen.add(value);
        }
        return value;
    };
};
```

**// File one**

```
function test1() {
    const util = new SomeUtil();
    util.remoteView = "audio#plivo_webrtc_remoteview"
    const onSave = () => {
        localStorage.setItem("SomeUtil", JSON.stringify(util, getCircularReplacer()))
    }
}
```

**// File 2**

```
function test3() {
    const util = new SomeUtil(localStorage.getItem("SomeUtil"));
    console.log(util.remoteView)
}
```

//

Comment: I did not understand your answer. Please elaborate your answer.

Comment: save only data can be serialised. function and methods cant be serialised.

Comment: I want to use function and method also. Then how can be it use ?

Comment: u cant, create a new instance of an object with the constructor.

Comment: Do you have any example ?