# How can I copy and save the structure of an object from the chrome developers console without a recursion error?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, recursion, console

I would like to save a JavaScript object from Chrome so I can dig into it a little bit. the problem is that the hierarchy of the object contains a reference to the window which reference the object, so when I attempt to copy it it throws a recursion error. How can I copy an object like this into an IDE so that I can insect it a bit ?

Comment: I get that recursion error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I print a circular structure in a JSON-like format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/how-can-i-print-a-circular-structure-in-a-json-like-format)