# Maximum call stack size exceeded - Object Initializer with reference to self

Tags: javascript, reference, this, object-initializers

While playing around with a simple *Javascript Object Initializer* example, I could not find an explanation while the following code:

```js
const obj = {
  self: this
};

console.log(obj);
```

would lead an `Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded`?

Meanwhile, a slightly different but may look similar initializer block as follows:

```js
const obj = {
  self: obj
};

console.log(obj);
```

would lead an `Error: Cannot access uninitialized variable.` while the following example using method initializers works perfectly fine:

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'Bob',
  a() {
    return obj.name;
  },
  b() {
    return this.name;
  },
};

console.log(obj.a());
console.log(obj.b());
```

Can you elaborate on the object initialization process and why the language allows the under initialization object and its `this` references usage inside method initializers and not in property values?

Comment: First doesn't throw for me, and also `this` doesn't equal to `obj`, which you probably intended. Second you just use the variable before it's declaration finished, which isn't allowed.

Comment: You're only declaring the functions, not calling them, so it doesn't throw. where as your second example is directly trying to access the `obj` before the variable is fully initialized.

Comment: #1 would not lead to any errors, rather to an unexpected value only, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers . You can create circular references in JS. Objects are stored in the memory, and only you get in JS is a reference, you can do even `const arr = []; arr[0] = arr;` without any issues.

Comment: @Teemu are you sure global `this` is undefined behavior? I've always seen `this === globalThis`

Comment: @Newbie I didn't say global `this` is undefined, I said it could be unexpected value, when you expect it to refer to `obj` (in OP's example).

Comment: @ASDFGerte indeed it throws in some context but not in others. Meanwhile I have no intention of having `self` refer to `obj` but simply experimenting with language semantics.
@pilchard this is also my obvious understanding. But I wanted more elaborate explanation in regards of the language design.
@Teemu thanks for the extra hint. I have already gone through the whole mentioned post answers which kinda cover part of the answers / explanations I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

#### Case 1 `this === global`

Here `this` is the global javascript context. Typically is huge and contains many circular references. When you `console.log()` an object with circular references the outcome depends on the implementation (it does not throw an error on `Chrome 93.0.4577.63`).

```js
console.log({ self: this });
```

[See what is `globalThis`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis)

[See how to print a circular reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/how-can-i-print-a-circular-structure-in-a-json-like-format)

#### Case 2 `obj is undefined`

This is invalid syntax. First the expression `{ self: obj }` will be evaluated, then the assignment will be performed. But when the expression is evaluated `obj` does not exist hence leads to `Error: Cannot access uninitialized variable.`.

```js
const obj = { self: obj };
```

This will do what you expect:

```js
const obj = {};
obj.self = obj;
```

#### Case 3

The last example is not related to the other examples at all.

- You never create a circular reference nor attempt to log one.
- You access `obj` from `a()` at a deferred time, so `const obj =`  has already been performed.

```js
const obj = {
    name: 'Bob',
    a() {
        // This is executed only when calling `a()`
        return obj.name;
    },
    b() {
        // `this` here is not the global context bu `obj`
        return this.name;
    },
};

// Both functions returns a string, so no circular dependency here 
console.log(obj.a());
console.log(obj.b());
```

This function will lead to the errors you see above:

```
const obj = {
    a() {
        obj.self = notExisting;
        return obj;
    },
    b() {
        this.self = this;
        return this;
    },
};
```