# Saving Matter.js engine.world as JSON

Tags: javascript, json, matter.js

I was wondering how if it was possible save my `engine.world` Object as an exportable format. I tried converting it as a JSON string js `JSON.stringify(engine.world)` as it contains a circular structure. Are there any ways to overcome this problem, or any other formats I could convert it to?

I want users to be able to be able to load custom worlds.

Comment: there are solutions for that ... a search for circular JSON reveals many ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I print a circular structure in a JSON-like format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/how-can-i-print-a-circular-structure-in-a-json-like-format)

Comment: Possibly an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). Even if you do save it, how are you planning on reconstituting the MJS state? There's potentailly a better way to achieve custom worlds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [resurrect-js](https://github.com/skeeto/resurrect-js)

You can stringify the data using:

```
var necromancer = new Resurrect();
var data = necromancer.stringify(engine.world);
```

You can then save `data` as a string in whatever text file you want.

To turn the string back into the object, you can use:

```
var world = necromancer.resurrect(data);
engine.world = world;
```

Hope this helps!