# Problem when trying to convert circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, circular-reference

In order to prevent that error regarding circular structure to JSON I have this function:

```
circular = () => { //fix circular stuff for json.stringify
  seen = new WeakSet();
  return (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
      if (seen.has(value)) {
        return;
      }
      seen.add(value);
    }
    return value;
  };
};
```

it works fairly well except in the case below:

```
var gameon = 1;
var fighter1 = {"userid":"97","username":"john","items":{},"ailments":{}};
var fighter2 = {"userid":"91","username":"james","items":{},"ailments":{}};
var resume = 30;

all = {"gameon":gameon,"fighter1":fighter1,"fighter2":fighter2,"resume":resume,"inturn":fighter1,"outturn":fighter2};
    
console.log(JSON.stringify(all,circular()));
```

it will print something like this:

```
{"gameon":1,"fighter1":{"userid":"97","username":"john","items":{},"ailments":{}},"fighter2":{"userid":"91","username":"james","items":{},"ailments":{}},"resume":30}"
```

Please notice how the output truncates after `resume`.

If I don't use the circular function then I get the correct output but also the "circular structure" error if I try to write to a file.

Why is that?

Comment: maybe irrelevant to the question, but where's the circularity in your example? I couldn't see any, so just pasted it into the browser console and tried `JSON.stringify(all)`, and got the expected JSON string with no errors.

Comment: @RobinZigmond There are mutliple references to the same `fighter1` and `fighter2` objects.

Comment: it only happens as you try to write that to a file. like this: `fs.writeFileSync(file,JSON.stringify(all,circular()),{encoding:'utf8',flag:'w'}); `

Comment: and when using your `circular` function, it is surely expected that the output is "truncated" as you put it, since the remaining values (`fighter1` and `fighter2`) have already occurred in the output and your function is explicitly designed to therefore exclude them. I think you're radically misunderstanding something about JSON and how the replacer function works in `JSON.stringify` (the latter is fair enough, I've never seen it in practice and just had to remind myself how it works) - but I'm not sure what.

Comment: @Barmar that's true but it's not circular - as I observed, it stringifies absolutely fine, just repeating the ouput. "circular" to me in this context means something like `const obj = { key: obj }; JSON.stringify(obj);` which will give this error.

Comment: but why does it happen only as I try to write to file?

Comment: Your function returns `undefined` if the value has already been seen. As the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) says: **If you return a Function, Symbol, or undefined, the property is not included in the output.**

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know - you don't show us the code where you try to write this to a file.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Circularity is often generalized to any shared references, since parsing the JSON will lose that sharing.

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you told it to do. It doesn't put the same object in the JSON multiple times. I suspect you only want to remove nested circularities (because they cause infinite recursion), not multiple references to the same object. But the replacer can't tell the difference.

Comment: no, it has the exact same function I posed here.

Comment: why open a new question then? why not comment there?

Comment: the problem is that you are returning nothing, and that's why, all properties with a  circular reference, will show nothing, as JSON.stringingy will remove all empty properties... you can, instead of `return:` write `return '[Circular]';` for example, but if you still need the full value, you need to store it and return that copied value

Comment: can't you just use the NodeJs function? `fs.writeFileSync(file, inspect(all), { encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'w' });`? you can get `inspect` from `const { inspect } = require('node:util');` it will show the references and point out what is circular

Comment: @balexandre It's already commented under the accepted answer and under another answer. This approach is buggy and doesn't work. It's shown with very simple examples.

Comment: What's the actual question? Do you want to know why your approach doesn't work? You can find the explanation in comments under the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11616993/16540390 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53731154/16540390. Do you want a working solution? You can use a different answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18354289/16540390

Comment: inspect seems to work for now. But why all the extra spaces in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Your `circular` function returns undefined for any already seen objects. JSON.stringify() comes across `undefined` and it stops processing the rest of the object. You can try to modify your function to add a placeholder for circular references:

```
   const circular = () => {
      let seen = new WeakSet();
      let placeholder = {};
      return (key, value) => {
        if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
          if (seen.has(value)) {
            return placeholder;
          }
          seen.add(value);
        }
        return value;
      };
    };
```

Comment: Thanks but even though I get no errors it turns out `inturn` and `output` return a {} value nstead of the actual values.