# Logging of an object in a local AWS Lambda shows only a short snippet and not the entire object

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda

I have developed an AWS lambda function and I am testing it locally on my machine. To run the function locally, I use the following template.yml.

If I log short strings, then the logging works without problems. However, if I want to log longer JS objects, only a small snippet is displayed and not the full object. How can I display the whole object?

**template.yml**

```
Resources:
  Function:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Timeout: 900
      MemorySize: 128
      Handler: index.handler
      CodeUri: /.../
      Runtime: nodejs16.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Environment:
        Variables:
    Metadata:
      SamResourceId: Function
```

```
const response = await axios.get(url);
console.log('test');
console.log(`${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
```

**Logging response:**

> 2023-07-29T11:50:02.629Z  8f7e4a8a-acad-4da9-ab7f-bca86e7a013a    LOG  test
>
> --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have circular references in the Axios response. Either use an npm module for this, check out suggestions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/how-can-i-print-a-circular-structure-in-a-json-like-format#answer-11616993) or better yet just print the relevant [data](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema) such as the `data` and `status` field:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify({ data: response.data, status: response.status }))
```