# Stringify timestamp object

Tags: javascript, json, object, serialization, stringify

How can i `JSON.stringify` the following data-structure?

```
var Records = {
    1357775376232: {
        pageX: 0,
        pageY: 0,
        scrollLeft: 0,
        scrollTop: 0,
        target: #document,
        type: null,
        value: undefined
    },
    1357775376243: {
        pageX: 69,
        pageY: 10,
        scrollLeft: 0,
        scrollTop: 0,
        target: <a>,
        type: "click",
        value: ""
    }
    // ...etc...
};
```

Comment: What is it about `JSON.stringify()` that doesn't work?

Comment: @Pointy nope, i get `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON ` And, [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9382383/1250044) does not help either...

Comment: Well that means you've got a non-serializable object.  If you would post what **exactly** the object looks like without the "... etc ..." part then somebody could possibly help.

Comment: What's `#document` and `<a>`? If they're DOM node references, they can't be serialized.

Comment: @bfavaretto Yeah, you're right... are there, any workarounds for that?

Comment: How about replacing them with selector strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a plain object, use the XPath for the elements.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this object contains references to `document` and to an `a` tag. You won't be able to serialize it until you remove such references.

A simple solution is:

```
var arrayWithRefs = [...];
var arrayWithout = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arrayWithRefs.length; i++) {
  arrayWithout[i] = {
    safeProperty: arrayWithRefs[i].safeProperty;
    // copy whatever you want, omitting document references
  };
}

var serialized = JSON.stringify(arrayWithout);
```

And of course there are libraries that can help you to pluck out just the properties you want. I would recommend **underscore** (general purpose) or **cryo** (exactly what you're attempting):

- [underscorejs.org](http://underscorejs.org)
- [cryojs](https://github.com/hunterloftis/cryo)

Comment: Full-disclosure, I'm the author of this library: https://github.com/hunterloftis/cryo - 'JSON on steroids' - it lets you do things like stringify around DOM elements without problems. Drop-in replacement for JSON.stringify/JSON.parse with lots of unit tests.