# How to create duplicate object

Tags: javascript, object, underscore.js

I have an `object` with nested `objects` like in the following way.

```
var g = {
    "steps": [{
        "location": [{
            "a": "1"
        }, {
            "a": "2"
        }]
    }]
};
```

I created duplicate object using `Object` like in the following way.

```
var h=Object.create(g);
```

The problem was,If I Modify anything in `h`,`g` also reflecting.How can I prevent this.I tried with `underscore` function(`clone`).

modified:

```
  h["steps"][0]["location"][0]["a"]="3"
```

After modify:

`g` looks like

[image]

`h` looks like

[image]

Even If I modify anything in `h`,`g` should not be reflect.

can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [`_.clone`](http://underscorejs.org/#clone) docs,

> Create a shallow-copied clone of the object. Any nested objects or arrays will be copied by reference, not duplicated.

Shallow copied objects tend to show the problem you are actually experiencing now. If the *object you use doesn't have any methods/variables attached to it*, you can do this

```
var h = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(g));
```

This does deep copy.

**Note:** If the object has circular references, then make use of the technique described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9382383/1903116)

Comment: Nice idea. Watch out for circular references though. And objects with non-standard prototypes.