# Passing an object with circular references from server to client-side Javascript while retaining circularity

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, circular-reference

I'm trying to pass an object with circular references from node.js server to client-side javascript.

Server (node.js):

```
var object = { circular: object }
//....
app.get('/', function(req, res){    
    res.render('index.jade', {object: object});
});
```

Client-side Jade/Javascript

```
script var object = !{JSON.stringify(object)};
```

Here I get the error that `object` contains circular references.

Any way to get the `object` in client-side javascript, **with**
<sup><strike>[or without](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)</strike></sup>
circular references?

Comment: You will have to remove any circular references before you stringify.

Comment: try sending from the node side: `res.render('index.jade', {object: util.inspect(object)});`

then on client side: `JSON.parse(object)`

Comment: here is a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11616993/736518

Comment: @adrichman: But `util.inspect` does return some string, neither an object nor JSON?

Comment: @timaschew It's a good solution but I've edited the question now to want a solution that actually *retains* the circularity, as that would be ideal.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382167/serializing-object-that-contains-cyclic-object-value and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/how-can-i-print-a-circular-structure-in-a-json-like-format

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Douglas Crockford has a solution for this that I have successfully used to solve this problem before: [Cycle.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/ad6079cbd8dc362a3cc42e1f97c01aa5ccd48bfe/cycle.js)

instead of just using `stringify` and `parse` you would first call `decycle` and restore with `retrocycle`

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(JSON.decycle(parent));
var restoredObject = JSON.retrocycle(JSON.parse(jsonString));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HY925/2/)

Comment: +1 and thanks for that link. I was 10% into inventing that in an answer and you just saved me a lot of time!

Comment: I found a library http://github.com/WebReflection/circular-json which I guess is an implementation of this

Comment: @laggingreflex, they are not the same.  I also found this implementation but cycle.js is smaller (most of it is comments) and worked better for me.

Comment: after retrocycle I didn't get the same object . :(

Comment: check out my answer. Essentially same method, but MUCH faster if object is large.

Comment: @mathheadinclouds Crockford's [official blog](https://www.crockford.com/blog.html) links to the same GitHub account this answer does.

Comment: in that case, Crockford is just not as good a programmer as I thought he was. What he delivered there belongs into the "bubble sort bin".

Comment: @mathheadinclouds If you believe that, you should contact him on one of his forums, here probably just submitting an issue on GitHub. He's usually excellent at responding... _iff_ he believes you have a good point. There may be some edge case yours misses, as an example, but if not, he may very well ask to integrate your code. If he does answer, I'm interested in hearing the results!

Comment: I installed cycle.js via `npm i cycle` but I get a TypeError: `JSON.decycle is not a function`. Do I need to import the decycle method? If so, how do I import it?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend my **siberia** package, which is up on [on github](https://github.com/mathHeadInClouds/siberia)

First, I'll explain the algorithm via example. Here is our example data structure (Joe likes apples and oranges, while Jane likes apples and pears.)

```js
var Joe = { name: 'Joe' };
var Jane = { name: 'Jane' };
var Apple = { name: 'Apple' };
var Orange = { name: 'Orange' };
var Pear = { name: 'Pear' };
function addlike(person, fruit){
    person.likes = person.likes || [];
    fruit.likedBy = fruit.likedBy || [];
    person.likes.push(fruit);
    fruit.likedBy.push(person);
}
addlike(Joe, Apple); addlike(Joe, Orange);
addlike(Jane, Apple); addlike(Jane, Pear);
var myData = { people: [Joe, Jane], fruits: [Apple, Orange, Pear] };
```

This gives us the following object graph (the root object, *myData*, is the tree with the crown, center left)

[image: ObjectGraph_IMG]

To serialize, we have to find a way of encoding the information contained in our object graph in a non-cyclical fashion.

When we determine the object graph by applying the a recusive `discover` function to the root object (`discover` is essentially depth first search with an added stop condition for already seen objects), we can easily "count" the nodes (objects) of the object graph, i.e., label them with consecutive integers, starting at zero (zero always being the label for the root). We'll then also "count" the encountered non-objects (or "atoms"); they'll get the negative integers as labels. In our example, all atoms are strings. [A more general example would contain other atom types - such as numbers and "quasi-atomic objects", e.g. regular expressions or date objects (JavaScript builtin objects having a standard way of stringifying them)]. For example, the pear gets number 8 simply because it's the 8th object discovered by our search algorithm. Here is the object graph again with those integer labels added.

[image: ObjectGraphWithLabels_IMG]

With the integer labels, serializing is easy. The "frozen version" of each object is an object with the same keys, but each of the values replaced by some integer. Each of these integers is an index into some table; either the objects table, or, in case the of a negative number, the atoms table.

Here is the objects table of our example.

[image: the13objects_IMG]

And the atoms table

[image: the5atoms_IMG]

For example, the frozen version of the pear object (which has `.name = "Pear"` and `.likedBy` = *array containing Jane*) is the object `{name: -4, likedBy: 9}`, because the atoms table has string "Pear" in slot 4, and the objects table has an array containing Jane in slot 9.

A slightly simplified version of the serialization algorithm (namely, one which does everything except deal with typing the atoms; especially, it will work for our example data structure) has only 32 lines of code, here it is:

```js
function forestify_aka_decycle(root){
    var objects = [], inverseObjects = new WeakMap(), forest = [];
    var atomics = {}, atomicCounter = 0;
    function discover(obj){
        var currentIdx = objects.length;
        inverseObjects.set(obj, currentIdx);
        objects.push(obj);
        forest[currentIdx] = Array.isArray(obj) ? [] : {};
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
            var val = obj[key], type = typeof val;
            if ((type==='object')&&(val!==null)){
                if (inverseObjects.has(val)){ // known object already has index
                    forest[currentIdx][key] = inverseObjects.get(val);
                } else {                      // unknown object, must recurse
                    forest[currentIdx][key] = discover(val);
                }
            } else {
                if (!(val in atomics)){
                    ++atomicCounter;                 // atoms table new entry
                    atomics[val] = atomicCounter;
                }
                forest[currentIdx][key] = -atomics[val];      // rhs negative
            }
        });
        return currentIdx;
    }
    discover(root);
    return {
        objectsTable: forest,
        atomsTable  : [null].concat(Object.keys(atomics))
    };
}
```

The objects table, being an array which in each slot contains a simple key-value pair list (with is a depth 1 tree), is called the forest, thus the name.
And since the trees of the forest are frozen, "siberia" was chosen as the name of the algorithm.

The reverse process (`unforestify` aka retrocycle) in even more straightforward: First, for each tree in the forest, generate either an empty array, or an empty plain object. Then, in a double loop over trees of the forest, and keys of the tree, do an obvious assignment, the right hand side of which is a "thawed" tree in the thawed forest we're just constructing, or a atom fetched from the atmoics table.

```js
    function thawForest(forestified) {
        var thawedObjects = [];
        var objectsTable = forestified.objectsTable;
        var atomsTable = forestified.atomsTable;
        var i, entry, thawed, keys, j, key, frozVal;
        for (i=0; i<objectsTable.length; i++){
            entry = objectsTable[i];
            thawedObjects[i] = Array.isArray(entry) ? [] : {};
        }
        for (i=0; i<objectsTable.length; i++){
            entry = objectsTable[i];
            thawed = thawedObjects[i];
            keys = Object.keys(entry);
            for (j=0; j<keys.length; j++){
                key = keys[j];
                frozVal = entry[key];
                thawed[key] = (frozVal>=0) ? thawedObjects[frozVal] : atomsTable[-frozVal];
            }
        }
        return thawedObjects;
    };
    function unforestify(forestified){ return thawForest(forestified)[0]; }
```

Above simplified versions of `forestify` and `unforestify` you can find in file siberiaUntyped.js (below 100 lines of code), which is not used, but provided for easier learning. Main differences between the simplified version and the real version are, first, atom typing, and second, the real version has non-recursive version of forsetify (little hard to read, admittedly), in order to prevent a stack overflow error you otherwise would get when you're dealing with extremely large objects (such as linked list with 100,000 nodes.)

#### Douglas Crockford

**Why siberia is faster than Douglas Crockford's decycle.js (2018 version), by an unbounded factor**: First, a similarity. Above `discover` function is similar to the function `derez`, which occurs inside of `.decycle`. Just as `discover`, `derez` is essentially depth first search with an additional stop condition if a previously encountered object is encountered once again, and in both cases, ES6 feature `WeakMap` is used to generate a lookup table of known objects. In both cases, the domain of the `WeakMap` consists of the nodes of the object graph (i.e., objects discovered so far.) But those objects are mapped to different things in `discover` vs `derez`. In `discover`, it's the object index, and in `derez` it's the path from the root to the object. That path is JavaScript code, which is later fed to `eval`, when we deserialize again.

For example, we already saw that our pear object is mapped (by `discover`) to the number 8, because it's the 8th object being discovered. Let's look at above depiction of the object graph, and trace the path from root to pear, i.e. 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8. We encounter objects root -> AllPeople -> Joe -> JoesFruits -> Apple -> AppleEaters -> Jane -> JanesFruits -> Pear. The keys (edge labels) we see between those objects are "people", 0, "likes", 0, "likedBy", 1, "likes", 1.

[image: fromRootToPear_IMG]

Now, in the Douglas Crockford version, we can do

```js
dougsFridge = JSON.decycle(myData)
dougsFridge.fruits[2].$ref
```

The result will be following string:

```js
$["people"][0]["likes"][0]["likedBy"][1]["likes"][1]
```

It is not surprising at all that of the many possible paths from root to pear, siberia and Douglas Crockfords algorithm found the same route. After all, both are depth first search with "seen already" stop condition added, garnished with storing some stuff.

The difference: Storing the the path takes up space which is linear in the number of nodes involved, which is unbounded, and in the other direction, from path to thawed object, that then has runtime which is linear in the number of nodes involved. On the other hand, in *siberia*, storing the information of the path takes constant space (just one integer is stored), and going back from that integer to the thawed object is just an array lookup, which takes constant time.

On top of that, `eval` and regular expressions are used, which can be slow (especially the latter), further degrading runtime performance. (This being by far not as bad as the other problem.)

here is a [speed test](https://mathheadinclouds.github.io/testsiberia/) page showing comparing siberia and Douglas Crockfords [cycle.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js)

Comment: that's nicely done. any chance you'll throw it into a git repo with a friendly license on it? i also wonder how it compares to built-in JSON.stringify().

Answer (score 0):

You cand easly do that with a "json-cycle" package.
It is well documented on https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-cycle
Here follows usage example for your case

```
npm i json-cycle
//...
const strJsonTree = JSON.stringify(jc.decycle(a));
console.log(strJsonTree);// you can even log 
send(strJsonTree);

// ...later 
// recieve the stream or string ..
const obj = jc.retrocycle(JSON.parse(somestring));
```

if you are using typescrpit you might need declare module on a d.ts file becouse I've found no @types/json-cycle on npm

```
declare module "json-cycle" {
  export function decycle(object: any, replacer?: (key: string, value: any) => any, depth?: number): any;
  export function retrocycle($: any): any;
}
```