# TypeError: cyclic object value in javascript while parsing hidden value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have one array, one json object like this

```
["www.flipkart.com","www.amazon.in"]
[
    {
        "product_name": "Deepcool",
        "dollar_price": 2.9697123914957047,
        "product_code": "C60_4123"
    },
    {
        "product_name": "Deepcool XFAN",
        "dollar_price": 5.473902300000191,
        "product_code": "C60_4123"
    },
    {
        "product_name": "DeepcoolXFAN80",
        "dollar_price": 5.473902300000191,
        "product_code": "C60_4123"
    }
]
```

I just set this object as hidden variable like below

```
<input value="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" class="graphobj1" type="hidden">
<input value="www.flipkart.com","www.amazon.in" class="graphobj2" type="hidden">
```

When i retrive this json object back from the page like this

```
var z1 = $('.graphobj1');
var z2 = $('.graphobj2');
```

and when i alert this , it shows the error `TypeError: cyclic object value`, how can i get my objects return back as it is?

Comment: How do you assign the object to the value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382167/serializing-object-that-contains-cyclic-object-value

Comment: use  JSON.stringify(object) to create the string you are asigning. Then jsut use JSON.parse() to get it back

Comment: I see no real reason for that error from the code you have shown. Is there anything else you are doing to the object? Also you can't store objects in values, you have to make them strings first.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** and **[`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)**

```js
var a = ["www.flipkart.com", "www.amazon.in"],
  b = [{
    "product_name": "Deepcool",
    "dollar_price": 2.9697123914957047,
    "product_code": "C60_4123"
  }, {
    "product_name": "Deepcool XFAN",
    "dollar_price": 5.473902300000191,
    "product_code": "C60_4123"
  }, {
    "product_name": "DeepcoolXFAN80",
    "dollar_price": 5.473902300000191,
    "product_code": "C60_4123"
  }],
  $input1 = $('input.graphobj1'),
  $input2 = $('input.graphobj2');

$input1.val(JSON.stringify(a));
$input2.val(JSON.stringify(b));

console.log(JSON.parse($input1.val()));
console.log(JSON.parse($input2.val()));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="graphobj1" type="hidden">
<input class="graphobj2" type="hidden">
```