# cyclic object value error when converting JSON object to String using JSON.stringify()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON object of format:

```
obj { 
    name: "abc" , 
    entriesList : "list of entry obj" , 
    propertiesList : "list of properties obj" 
};
```

where entry is also another object

```
entry { 
    info : "data obj" , 
    age : "15" , 
    subjects : "5"
}
properties { 
    a : "a" ,  
    b : "b" 
}
data { 
    c : "c" , 
    d : "d"
}
```

Using `JSON.stringify()` it is giving error

> cyclic object value

How should I convert my object to JSON string?

Comment: Isn't JSON.parse reverse of JSON.stringify i.e. converting JSON string to JSON obj? whereas my need is stringily

Comment: Is your JSON cyclic? Is the original 'obj' an entry object?

Comment: @crc442 No, it does't looks cyclic to me. Original obj is not an entry object.

Comment: Can you post the actual data?

Comment: I can't post actual data but I am trying to come up with more clear analogy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serializing object that contains cyclic object value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382167/serializing-object-that-contains-cyclic-object-value)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a cycle from your example, but the idea is to not include cyclic references in your object. I mean to avoid something like this:

```
var a = {}, b = {};
a.child = b;
b.child = a; //This will cause a cyclic reference when calling JSON.stringify both on a and b object
```

Comment: I understood not to include cycles references and I can't see cyclic references as well.But I am getting error as cyclic object value.