# JSON.stringify cyclic object n^2

Tags: javascript, json, hashcode, cyclic-reference

I need to JSON.stringify a possibly cyclic object, which means that I have to pre-process the object and remove cycles. I'm already aware of the [n^2 indexOf solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382167/serializing-object-that-contains-cyclic-object-value).  Since that javascript doesn't seem to expose an object id or memory location, nor a generic hashcode for any object, is there a way to make the containment check faster?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serializing object that contains cyclic object value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382167/serializing-object-that-contains-cyclic-object-value)

Comment: An ES6 `Set` object can keep track of objects visited directly.  Work-arounds when that is not available usually involve adding a non-enumerable uniquely generated string key to each object so you can put that in a regular object map which is shown here in this polyfill: https://github.com/jfriend00/ES6-Set/blob/master/set.js

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks, that's probably what I was looking for. do you mind making that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ES6 Set object can keep track of objects visited directly.  As you're traversing through the object, you put each object into the Set and then a simple `objSet.has(obj)` will tell if you've already encountered this object of not.

Work-arounds when that ES6 Set is not available usually involve adding a non-enumerable uniquely generated string key to each object so you can put that in a regular object map which is shown here in this [ES6 Set polyfill](https://github.com/jfriend00/ES6-Set/blob/master/set.js).