# How to have JSON.stringify tell you which field is forming a circular reference?

Tags: node.js

I have some code that is taking any ol' object and trying to output it as JSON. The problem is that in one of these cases it insists there is a circular reference and thus fails.

According to my debugger this isn't the case (but then again, I don't know the traversal logic for this function either so I can't be sure).

What would be great is to have

> JSON.stringify say "Converting circular structure to JSON 'foo.baz.bat' "
>   where 'foo.baz.bat' is the first offending reference.

Is there a way to do this **without implementing my own custom replacer**? For this particular part of the code it's job should ONLY be to format to JSON and absolutely nothing more. Meaning: I don't want to massage the data here if that's what it takes.

To be clear: What makes this different from other posts suggesting that I write a custom replacer to munge-out the data is that I just need this to debug what the offending member is.

Something already built in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serializing object that contains cyclic object value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382167/serializing-object-that-contains-cyclic-object-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [json-stringify-safe](https://github.com/isaacs/json-stringify-safe)

And the offending field will be shown as `[Circular]`, like this:

```
{
  "circularRef": "[Circular]",
  "list": [
    "[Circular]",
    "[Circular]"
  ]
}
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Can I get an up vote on the question?