# Want to check function body of console.log in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to see function body of `console.log` function.
To check this I tried following code :

```
console.log(console.log.toString())
```

It prints only

> function () { [native code] }

So how can I check this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  It is a native function, which under most browsers means it is written in a lower-level language like `C`.

If you can explain why you would like the source, we might be able to help.

Comment: When I pass circular object to console.log,it prints correctly.
Whereas when I use winston for logging & pass circular object,it goes into infinite loop.So I want to check ,how it is handled in console.log.

Comment: Each browser is free to handle it howeer they'd like.. but -- there are some JSON encoders that can handle circular data.  One of them might be able to help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382167/serializing-object-that-contains-cyclic-object-value  or google for Circle JavaScript Encoder.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy,
Your comment helps me & gave a proper direction to this problem.