# How to serialize and store the returned routing object locally in leaflet routing machine?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, osrm

I am thinking of caching the returned routing object in leaflet routing machine. But I cannot serialize the object using JSON.stringify() as it throws up an error stating it's a circular object. I tried to use some java script libraries that can overcome this, but de-serializing it is destroying the object.

```
var control = L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
        L.latLng(57.74, 11.94),
        L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)
    ],
    geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),
    routeWhileDragging: true,
    reverseWaypoints: true,
    showAlternatives: true,
    altLineOptions: {
        styles: [
            {color: 'black', opacity: 0.15, weight: 9},
            {color: 'white', opacity: 0.8, weight: 6},
            {color: 'blue', opacity: 0.5, weight: 2}
        ]
    }
});
```

Help me in storing the control object locally and retrieve it again to add it to the map.

Comment: Im not sure what do you mean by "but de-serializing it is destroying the object" what libraries have you used?

Comment: dojox json ref library. Thing is we can just use control.addto(map) to render the map. but the de-serialized control object throws an error which  is "addto is not specified".

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot serialize the object using JSON.stringify() as it throws up
>   an error stating it's a circular object

It seems that you have an object with circular references, I would suggest using the second parameter of stringify as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382167/serializing-object-that-contains-cyclic-object-value), but this may cause problems as it removes anything that appears more than once not just cyclic references.

checkout this [plugin](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) hope it will work for you.